# What's the missing column/row? (GCJ 2016-1A rankfile)

Tags: code-golf

There is an `N x N` square of numbers.

- All columns increase strictly monotonically from top to down
- All rows increase strictly monotonically from left to right
- There is exactly one valid answer for each input.

You are given `2N-1` rows of `N` numbers representing rows or columns in this square. The task is to find the row that isn't in the input.

**Your Task**
Write a program or function that outputs the row or column that isn't in the input.

**Input**

First, you get the number `N`.
Then follow `2N-1` lines of `N` space-separated numbers, representing rows or columns of this `N x N` square. The lines are given in left-to-right or top-down order. There may be multiple equal lines. It is ok to omit the initial `N` from the input, or modify the input format as you like.

```
3
1 2 3
2 3 5
3 5 6
2 3 4
1 2 3
```

**Output**

Your program or function should output a single line of `N` numbers; the row or column from the square that was not present in the input. You may change the output format as you please.

```
3 4 6
```

This would correspond to one of two squares:

```
1 2 3     1 2 3
2 3 4     2 3 5
3 5 6     3 4 6
```

Either way, the output is the same.

**Bonus**

Your solution should be able to calculate `2 ≤ N ≤ 10` within a minute on a normal computer. If your solution handles the big input, `2 ≤ N ≤ 50`, within a minute, you get `-10%` byte count.

**Test cases**

```
2
22 222
2 22
22 222
-> 2 22


3
1 2 3
2 3 5
3 5 6
2 3 4
1 2 3
-> 3 4 6

4
11 14 16 22
3 6 9 11
6 7 11 14
9 11 15 19
10 11 19 22
6 7 10 11
3 6 8 10
-> 8 10 15 16
```

Note that you can simply change what line in these inputs that is omitted, and reorder them in any way you want, to generate new test cases.

This is a simplified version of Google Code Jam 2016 round 1A problem B: Rank and File. The original Google Code Jam problem, where you can get more test cases (but without answers), is available here: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4304486/dashboard#s=p1

Comment: You should make the N input optional - many languages would just read and discard/ignore it because it can be inferred from the rows.

Comment: Changed it to allow omitting `N` from input.

Comment: More generally, I think you should adapt your I/O format to be more flexible by letting languages do input and output in their native list types. See [Things to avoid when writing challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260).

Comment: I/O rules further loosened :)

Comment: Removed bad testcase. It should follow the original as close as possible, but with a simpler problem statement and only a single testcase per run.

Comment: If there's a bonus for test cases of a certain size, you should include such a test case in the question body.

Comment: This strikes me as a [chameleon challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260). Once you solve the puzzle, you find that it's really about cancelling duplicates.

Comment: We also [discourage bonuses in code golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/20469)

Comment: After reading the answers, I realize this was indeed an accidental chameleon challenge. I did not know about the simple solution, and that's not how I solved it myself. I tried to simplify the description as far as I could.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 5 - 10% = 4.5

This is an unnamed function (block) that takes an array of arrays and returns an array:

```
{:^$}
```

(With some inspiration from Dennis)

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=e%23%20the%20input%3A%0A%5B%5B1%202%203%5D%0A%5B2%203%205%5D%0A%5B3%205%206%5D%0A%5B2%203%204%5D%0A%5B1%202%203%5D%5D%0A%0A%7B%3A%5E%24%7D%0A%0A~p%20%20e%23%20execute%20and%20pretty%20print)

And here is the code I actually submitted at GCJ (24 bytes):

```
li2*({l~}*]$e`{(2%*~}%S*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li2*(%7Bl~%7D*%5D%24e%60%7B(2%25*~%7D%25S*&input=3%0A1%202%203%0A2%203%205%0A3%205%206%0A2%203%204%0A1%202%203)

**Explanation:**

This basically lists the values that appear an odd number of times.

```
:^    reduce by symmetric difference; pairs of duplicate values "cancel" each other
$     sort the resulting array
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3.6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œ^/Ṣ
```

The source code is **4 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-10% bonus**. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZNeL-G5og&input=&args=W1sxLDIsM10sWzIsMyw1XSxbMyw1LDZdLFsyLDMsNF0sWzEsMiwzXV0)

#### How it works

Since there are **2N** rows/columns in total, each number must appear **2N** times. Therefore, it suffices to take the numbers that appear in an odd number of the **2N - 1** rows/columns from input.

```
œ^/Ṣ  Main link. Argument: A (2D list of integers)

  /   Reduce the rows by...
œ^    symmetric multiset difference.
   Ṣ  Sort the result.
```

Comment: Damn, this is impressive. Also, obligatory "but this is eight bytes in Unicode" comment-- wait, you linked the codepage this time! Never mind.

Comment: Obligatory *Unicode is not an encoding* response.

Comment: For Pyth, it is still 12 bytes using your algorithm... One does not simply outgolf Dennis.

Comment: Oh, it's 11 bytes now.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 179 bytes

```js
f=(n,a,p=[],o)=>(p[n-1]?p.every((_,j)=>~(a.map(v=>v+"").indexOf((m=p.map((_,k)=>p.map(r=>r[k]))[j])+""))?1:o=!o&&m):a.map((c,i)=>o=o||f(n,x=a.slice(),p.concat(x.splice(i,1)))))&&o
```

### Explanation

Whew! That took quite a bit of effort to do without any combinatorics built-ins...

Possibly qualifies for the bonus. I haven't tested with `n = 50`.

The entire function is a recursive permutation function. It takes the size `n` and input array `a`, then moves each item individually from `a` to the current permutation array `p`. `p` becomes every permutation of *rows*.

Once the length of `p` becomes `n`, it transposes `p` to get an array of the columns. It searches these columns for each item in `a`.

Because `a` should contain all these columns except one if this is the correct result, output the column in the transposed `p` which is missing from `a` if there is only one column missing.

```js
f=(n,a,p=[],o)=>(
  p[n-1]?                                        // once p is a square
    p.every((_,j)=>                              // find each column in the transposed square a,
                                                 //     a is missing a column so one should fail
      ~(a.map(v=>v+"")                           // convert column arrays to strings so we can use indexOf
        .indexOf(                                // search for current column
          (m=p.map((_,k)=>p.map(r=>r[k]))[j])+"" // transpose p to match a
        )
      )?1:o=!o&&m                                // if there is only one column missing from a, o = missing column
    )
  :a.map((c,i)=>                                 // add each row to the permutation
    o=o||                                        // set o to first found result
    f(n,x=a.slice(),p.concat(x.splice(i,1)))     // get next permutation
  )
)&&o                                             // return o

// Test
var testCases = [[
    2, [
      [22,222],
      [2,22],
      [22,222]
    ]
  ], [
    3, [
      [1,2,3],
      [2,3,5],
      [3,5,6],
      [2,3,4],
      [1,2,3]
    ]
  ], [
    4, [
      [11,14,16,22],
      [3,6,9,11],
      [6,7,11,14],
      [9,11,15,19],
      [10,11,19,22],
      [6,7,10,11],
      [3,6,8,10]
    ]
]];
document.write("<pre>"+testCases.map(c=>f(c[0],c[1])).join`\n`);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 9 x 0.9 = 8.1 bytes

```
S{f%/QT2Q
```

Flattened list as input.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7Bf%25%2FQT2Q&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0)

#### previous 11-byte solution

```
M-+GH@GHSgF
```

Uses Dennis' algorithm.

#### previous 12-byte solution:

```
S{f%/.nQT2.n
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7Bf%25%2F.nQT2.n&input=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%2C5%5D%2C%5B3%2C5%2C6%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%5D&debug=0)

### alternative 13 byte solution:

```
eCf%hT2rS.nQ8
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eCf%25hT2rS.nQ8&input=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%2C5%5D%2C%5B3%2C5%2C6%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: If you take a flat list as input (I guess that's allowed), you can shorten your 12-byte solution to 9 bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, but I still cannot outgolf you :D

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 19.8 bytes

```
x->sort(symdiff(x...))
```

The source code is **22 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-10% bonus**. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPnNvcnQoc3ltZGlmZih4Li4uKSkKCnByaW50KGYoZihbMSAyIDM7MiAzIDU7MyA1IDY7MiAzIDQ7MSAyIDNdKSkp&input=)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 62 bytes

```
(a,s=[])=>[for(b of a)for(c of b)s[c]^=c]&&[for(c of s)if(c)c]
```

Only works for positive integers. 64 bytes to work with zero too:

```
(a,s=[])=>[for(b of a)for(c of b)s[c]^=~c]&&[for(c of s)if(c)~c]
```

101 bytes to work with arbitrary floating-point numbers:

```
(a,m=new Map)=>[for(b of a)for(c of b)m.set(c,!m.get(c))]&&[for(b of m)if(b[1])b[0]].sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

109 bytes to work with strings instead:

```
(a,m=new Map)=>[for(b of a)for(c of b)m.set(c,!m.get(c))]&&[for(b of m)if(b[1])b[0]].sort((a,b)=>(a>b)-(a<b))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5  - 10% = 4.5 bytes

Port of the CJam answer - reduce by symdiff, sort.

```
{^}*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfHW1kpGBkZBTLFQ2iQRSEH/u/Oq5WS@V/wn8A)