# How many lights are on?

Tags: code-golf, counting

You are little speck on a Cartesian plane. Pondering your existence, you decide to roam around your plane and touch things. You notice that every coordinate pair you visit has a light switch. To entertain yourself, you decide to toggle every switch that you come across.

**The Challenge**: Create a program that will take an input of random length, using only the characters `v`,`^`,`<`, and `>`. These characters correspond to movements.

- `<` moves you one unit to the left
- `^` moves you one unit up
- `>` moves you one unit to the right
- `v` moves you one unit down

Using this randomly generated input, calculate how many switches will be left in the `ON` position, assuming you start at (0,0), all lights begin in the `OFF` state, and you don't turn on any lights until you make your first move. (Meaning, if you start at (0,0), and move up 1 unit to (0,1), there will now be **1** light on). If you come across a switch that is on the `ON` position, it will be turned `OFF`.

Test cases:

```
v>v<^^<v<<^<^><<>^^>>><v>vv^v>v^><><<^>><<<vvv^vvv>v>>v><vv^^<<>vv^^>v^<>>^^<^^>^^v<^>^<vvv^v^v><^<<v<<>><<>v>>^><^>^^<>>>>vv>^<<^<<><vvv<v^>>vvv>v^>>><<v^>^^^^v>>^>^v>v<vv^<>^<<v>vv>><^^<^><vv^^v<v<v^^^>v<^vv^v<><vv^^^>v^>v>vv<<^><v<^v><<v^^v>>v<vv<><^^^v<^v><><<^^<>^>><^^^>vv^<>>>>^<^<<<<>>>v<<v<v<vv><<vv<vv<^v^^^>>vv<>v>><<<v^>vv><v<<<v<<>^vvv^<v^v>^^v^v><<v^>>>v<v<v^>>>v><>>>^<><<<<>vv>v><v>v><^v<>v>>>vv<<>^>^>v<^><^<^vv^><^^>v<^^v>v^v<^^^^vv<>v<>><v^^><>v<<<>v^<v^^><>^<>^<>><>^^<>^v><>>><v<^^>>v>^^^<v
```

yields 125 lights on.

```
>>><^>>>^vv><^^v^<<<>>^<>>^<^>^<<^^v^<v^>>^<<><<>^v<^^^vv>v><^>>^<^<v><^v<^<<^^v><>>^v<^>^v<vvv<<<v^vv>>^vv>^^<>>vv>^<^>vv<>v^<^v<^^<v^^^<<^><><>^v>vvv<^vvv<vv><vv<^^v^^<^^>>><<<>^<>>><^<<<>><>^v><^^vv<>>><^^^<^>>>>v<v^><<>v<v<v^<<^><v^^><>v>^<>^^^vvv<v^>^^^^v>v<v>>>v^^<v<vv>><<>^vv><<vv<<>^^v>>v<^^v>><v<v<<>^^vv>>^v>v>v<>^>^v<>>><>v>v<<v<^<>>>vv>>v>^<>vv^v><><^v^>v<^^>v<^v>>v^>^>>v>v>^>^<^^>vv>>^vv<^><>^><<v^<><<^<^>^^vv^<<^^<^^v<v<>^>v>>>>>>vv<<v>^>vv^>^><^<^^><<vvvv>vvv<><<><v^vv><v^^<>^>><^vv<><>^>vv>>>vv^vv<<^v^^<<v^^>^>vvv<><<v>^>^>v<v>^<^^^^<^>^>><>>^^vv<>v<^>v><v<v^>>v<^v<vv>v^>v<v^<^^^^v<^<^<<v<<<v<v^^>vv^>><<<v>>^^^>^<^>>>v^v><^^vv^>><^^vv<vv<v^><>>^><<<>>^^v^v<<v^<vv^^^>><>>^v^^^>>^>^<<^>v>^^v>><>v>^>vv^^<vvvv<><^v>^><<>>><^<^v^<<vvv^v<<<<<><><<><><<v>v<v>v><^v^^vvv>><>^>^>^v<<vv^^^v^vv><v><><v<v<<>>>v<^<^v<<>^v<<^v<><>v>>^^>^<v^<<^v^^^vv>><v^<v>^v><^<>>>>^^<vv<>^^>^>v^v^^>><>^^<^v^<v<<v<^<<^^vv>v>^<vv<<^^v^vv^>^^<>v>^>^<>vv><v>>><<><<vv^^<vv<>>^v>^<<vv>^><<>^<v>v><<v^<v<><v>^<^<^><^^^^>>>^<>^^><>>v^<vv^<^<<vvvv>>>v^v>>^>v^><<>>v<>>^>><vvvvv<<vvvv<v>^v<vv^<>><<><v^^<^<v>^v<^<<>^v<v^<>v<<>^<<vvv><^><^^^<>>v^<<>vv><^^^>><^>v^v>v<v^>>v>>v>vv<<v<<vvv^^^>^<v^^<^<v<^<>>v^<<v>>v^><v<vvvvv^^^<v^^<><v<<^>>^><^<v^v^^>><v><>v>^<vvvv><<v^^v^>^>v>><>^^v>v^>vv^>v<^<<^vv^>vv^<v>^<v^<>^v>v^>v^<<>^^<^>^^>vv^>>vv>v>vvv><>^v<<<<v^>v^^v<><v<v>^<^><^><<v<>><<>v^^>>><<><>>><<>><v^^>><^>><^<>v^^vvv>v<^<<vv^>vv^><<>v><>^<>v^^v>^>v^<>^><v>^><<^v<v^^<v>><^^>>^<^<^v<v>^>^<^<v><><>>>><>^<^<v>v<v^>v><>v^>v^<<><^<>>v<^vv^^^>^<<<<>^>^<><^vvv>^^<v^v>v>v^v>v>>vv>^><>^vv>^<v<v^<>vv^<v<><>^>>vvv><>>^<<v^<<>^<v^>v<^^^<^<^^<>^>>v>^<v>vv<v^^>><<<<<>>v>^v>^>>>>v>>^^>^<<<^<<<v>>^><<<<^vv<<>^v<^>v^<v<<>v<>^<^<^<^<>>^^^vvv<v>^vv>^><^<v^>^v<v>><><vvv<^^>>v<^v>^>>>><v^<v^^<^^v<vvv<v>^^<<>><^<v^v<^vv>v>vv>^^<>^^^^>>^v><vv<<<v>^v^>>v^>><<<^v^v<<>><<vvvvv<v^vv>vvvv><v^v<^^^><vv^^<>><>><^>^^^^v>v><><v^<>^v<>^^<^^>^^^vvv>>vv^v^<v<vv^v>v>>>^v^^vv^<^v>v^v>>^v>v<v^<^^><vvv>><<>><>><v>v<^<v>>>>v^^v^^>^><<v><^<<>>v<>^^<<>vv^>>vv^^^v>>>^v^><v<<^>v<v><>>>^>>^<<>>^><<vv<^^>^^^v^^<>>>vv><<>v<><<<>v<<>>>v<>v<>^<vv^v<^^<<<v>^v>>^^>^><<^vv<><><>v>^v>^<>v>>^^^<^^>>vv>v<<<v^><<v><^v><>v<^<<^<>^vv>^><^^^^^<<v^^<>v>><^<v^^^vv>^v<>^<v<v>v>^><^<<^<>><^^>vv^<>^<>vv<>>v<vv^>><^^<^>v<><>vv<v<>>v><v^^^>^^^<<vv^><^^v>v>^<^>v^><<vvv>v^><vv<><^<><^>^v<><<v^<<><>^^^^<<^>>^>^v^>v>^<<^>vv^vv^v<>^<<^>v<^^<<v<v<<<^>vv^>><>v>><><v>v><v^><vvv>vv<<vvv>v^<<^v<^<><<^v>v<>>vv<<v^>v>v<<>>^vv^<^^^<^v>>^<vv>^<v>><>v>^^<<v^<>>>>>v^v>><>v^>>^<>>^<^vvv^^^<^v<><vvv^>^>v><<v>>^v>v<v>v^<v>v>^<>vvv>vvv^^<>vv>^^^^^>v<<^v<>>>><<<>>><vv>>^v^^v<v^>>>^>^v<^v>^v<>vv<><vvv^v<<<<v<vv>vv^<^vvv<^v>v^^vv<^>>>^^>>^^><>^>>v<>>>^^<<v<^<<<<<^^<v^^^<<>><<<^>^v^>vv<>>>^^v><<>^^^^<vvv><^^<>>>^><<^>><v>^<>^v^<vvvv^>>^><<>><^<v^>>vv^vv<^>>>><^>^v<^<v<^^<^<^><^<>>^<>v^v<<>v>v<>><<v<^v<<<^v<v<>><v<^<^>>v>v>><v^<v><>>>>>v^v>><^<^<v>><v^v>v<>v<v><<<>^^><>^^<^vv^^<>v><><><^>^^v^vv^<><>>>>v><>>^>^<<^<v<v^>v^^<v>>><<^^vv^^>><<^<vvvvv>><^>^>>^vv<><<>v>v^<<<^v<^^<<^vv>v<vvv><^v>vv^vvvv<^>^v^<<<<^v<<<>^vvv>^v><<>>v<v<^v^<>v>>^^v^vv>>>^v^^>>^<><><<<<^vv>>>>>v>v^>v<>><<<>^vv>^^^^<^^^>^^^^>^^^v^v><^>^>>>v<v<^<^^<<^v<<^<>vvv^^^^v^<<>vv>^^>>><^^v<^<<<v<>v<<><>v<><>^<v<<^>^^>><<v>^^><^^v<^<v^<^^<>^<>^v^>>^^v^v^<>v<>^<<<>^v^v>^<vvvv<>v<<>vv^<<>vv>>>>^<v><>>>v^><<>^v>><<>>^^v><^<>>vv^^^>vv^<^^v><v>>vvv^v<^v>v<<^^<>v^^^v^^>><v^>>v^v^vv<^>v^<^>^>v<v^><vvv^>^<>v<<^><^^<vv>v>>vv>v^>>^vvv>>v^>^^>vvv>>v><<>>^^v>v<v<><<<<^^v<^<>^v>><v^^^<>>vvv>v><<v>^^<^vvvv^v>v>^vv>^vv^^v><<>>^^>>v>>>^v><^>v<^^<>vv>v>v^^^>>^^^><<<<>>^>>^<^v<^<^<>^><v<<v>v<>^>>^<<v^^<v^vvvvv>>v^>>^^^<^^<><<><><>^v>vvv^>^^>v<^^>^<<^v^^^><>><<v<^^^<<<<>><>><<^^v><v^<<^v<v><<>^<v>^>^v>vv>><v^<^<v<v<v><^^^^>>><^<><^v^v<<<^>vv^<v^>^^v^>>><<<<^<>>><v>>>vv^>^^<v^v>>>v^<^<>vv>^v^^><<<v>v>v>><>>>v<^>^<>>^^<v^<<^<v^>><^v^><><v><><v^vvv<<>v>>><<><v>v<>>><^<^^v<v>^<<>^v>^>^>^^<^^><^>>>>><^^>vv>^<^^<><^>^<^^><^<v>v^>><^>^^^>>v^v<^>>^<v^<>^><><v>>^v<v^^^^v<^vv><^v>>^^^<>^<^<^>vv^v<<>vv>^<>v>^>^>vv^v<vv<^^^v<v>v>v^<^^^v><v<<<^^<><^^>>>><<^^v<<^>v<<vv^^^vv^vv^<v><>^v<v>>><vv^v<v^>>>>^<<<vv^>>v>^><<><<^<^><<vv^>v^>><>v^<<<>v^><>><<>>v><>v^<v><>^v>>><><>>>^vvv^v>vv>>>^^v^><<v<>>^^^v^^><<^v<><><v<<v<v<><<<v^<^^^<>v^^v<^^<<^>v<<v><^<<<<>><>^v>^<>^<^^v^vvv>^^<>^>><v^^vv^<>^<><<^^^v<^^^>>^^v>^>^<^>v><<^<>^v<><vv^vv<><<<<<<v<<v<<vv^<<^<^vvvv><v^v^v<>>>vvvvv^<vv^<^<>vv>^<><<v><>v^^<v<>>>vvv^><^<^>v^^<v>^<>>>^^v^<vv<<<<^><v<<<>v<<<v<>>^^^>^><>v>^v^>^<v^^><^v^^<^v^^>^v>>^^^<<><><<<>v>><^><>>>vvvv>v>>v>^^^^v<><vv<^<v^v>>^^vv<^>vvv>^v>>><v<v<v^<^>^^<vvv<vv<v>>^vv>^<<^<^<v>v^<vv^^^v>vv<v><v><v>^<v>>vv<>v>^^>v^^^<>v<>v^v<>^<><v><^>^<v^v><<^v^v^v<<v><<^^<^vv>^<^v><>v>><v^v^>><><><<<v<>v<^vv>v<v<<>^vvvvv^<<<^<vv><<><>v^<^v<<<^>v>v<v^<<^>v<<^<v><<<^>vv>v>^<^^v>>>><>vv>>vv>vvv<>^^<>^v^<>vvv<^^^vv>v><<<<vv^v><v^<^<<<><v<>^><<>^>v<^^<<>v>>v<<>><^^<<<^<^vv^^>v>v<>^^>>^v^vvv>^v^>v>>v>v>v>>vv^<><<<<>v^^>vv<^^v>>v<vv<^>>^<>^^v<><vv^<><v><v<<v^v<^^<^v^v<>v<<><vvv><<<^<^^<<>>^v>>>^v>>>v<>>^><<<><><<<v<vv<^<>v^^v^^>^<<^^^v^>^<<^>^>^>>>>v<v<v<>vv<<vv^<<^<vv>^^<^<<>><^v><><>^<v><v^>^v>^<^>^^><v><<^<v^^<<^><><v>v<>>><<^><v<^vvv^<<<>><<>^v^^><vv>vv<>^>^>vv<>v^<^<>vv><<>^<v<vv<^<^<><^vv<<^>>>v<>><<>>>^^^^<<^v>>v<vv>^^>v<v<vv^><<><>>>v>>^^v<^v^^>>v^<>>v^>><^<^^v<v<><<><>>^<>><^v<^^^^><>^>vv>>^vv<<>v<<<<<<><<<><<>><v><^^^<>>v<^><^vvv<>^>^^v>^<v><^v^vv^<<>v<<<<v>^vv>>v>vv<<^>^<>>vvv^<v<><>><>^^^^vvvvvvv<<>v<^><^^>vv^^<v<<^^<vvv<v<v<<>><<><v^^>><^<>^v^vv<<v<v<>><<>>>>>^vv<><v<>v><v>v>><v<v^vvvvv<><>v>>v<><<<^^<>^<^^<v>v^<vv>^vv^<>^<<^<vv><v<v>>v>^<>v^<<v^<v>^v<>><v>>>>^<<^^^v<^<>><^<><v>>vv^>^<^<^>>v^>^^^^>vvvvv>^v<^><^^<^^>^<^^^^^^^>v>>vv>v^^^v^^^<>v><^>>>v>^>^>^>vv<vv<^^>>^>>>v<>v><<^<<v^>^>>>>^^><^^<v<<<<>>v>v^v^^<>><v<^<<<<v^^^^<v<<<^>v>^^<vv<^^^^^v>^v^<v><>>^^>^v>^>^vv^v>v>v^>v>^>>^^^^>>^>>^><>><v>v>>><<^v^v^>^>^>>vv><<^>v<v<v^<<>>^v<<^v<<^><^>>^<v>^>vv>v>^^^>v^^<^<^^>vv>^^><v>>^v>^v<<^^^<<^v^>^<<^>vv^>>^<^v><<>v><^^^<^^>>vv>^vv>><^<<<^>vv^v>v<^<<<^<^<<><^^>>>v^<^^^>^<><^v>>^<<v<^v>>v^<^<^<^^^<v^><<vvv^<^v^vv^vv<v<<v<^<>^v>^^^<^^v<v<v><<<^<>^^^^v>v^v^v^v<v><v>>^v><vv^^^v>><<v^vvvv<<<^v<<><^>^<v^^v<>vvvv^vv<>^v<><>^^<>>vvv<^>><v^<<>v>v<>^v^>v^>><<>>^^<^v<>>^>^><>>^<v<v^^<^v><v^<v<><><^<<><v^v<<>vv<v<v<^>>><>vv^^<><<v<^^<<^<><^^^>^>>>^<^>>>^>><^^^<^v^^^v^v^v>v>v><vv>><vvv<<v><><^^>^v<v>><v><^><^<<>v^vv^v><^vv>^>>v<vv><^<^^v<^^vv<vv<v<v>v><v<vv<<>^^v^^v<<<^<>v^^^<><>>><^>v^^^v^vv<<<^>>v><^>v^<>>>>^<>^^vvv^^<><^>^^<><>^vvv^^<vv^>vv^^^^v<>vv<^^^v<<>><<vvvvv>v>^^^vv>><v><v<>vvvv<v^><^<>^>^<>v>v>v^vvvv<><^v>>>^^>><vvv<>^>^v^<vvv>v^vv^vv><>><>v^^v^vv<^v>vv>>v<v><^<<^v<>>^vv^<v>v><v>v>^v>^<v>^<<^>vv>v<^<^vv^<^><<<v<<^^vv<vvv><>v>v<vv^<><><^vvv>>vv<^^^v><^v><<^>^^v>^<>><v<>>^^<<<v><>^>^><vvvv<>^<<<><<<^<>>v^vv^>><^vv^^>^<v^<v>><^^>>>^v>^v<>^v<><^><vv>v^^^<^>>^<<^<^><<<^^<v<<^vv<^<>v<^<<^^<v<vv<<><v<v^<>^<>v>>v<^v>v<>^^vvv<>vv^v^<><v^vv^<^v^v><>^><v^<>>^^^<>>vv^<v>^^v><v<^>^^^^^^><>>vvv<<><><v<^>v<>v^v<<<<>v^>>>>^v>^^<v^>v><v^<^^v<<<<v<<<>^v<^>^v>v^^>v^^vvv>vv<>^>v><v<>^<vv><>>><<^>>><<v>v^^<^<<<<v^<>>>v<<<^v^vv<>^v>v<<<<>^^>><v><>v<v><^^>><>^>^>v>>><v>^vvvv<><><^>>^v^><<>^v<><><^><<<>v^^>v>^>v^<v^vv<>><^vv^^>^^><vv<<>v>v^^>><v^>^<^<>>>vv<>^>v>v^<>v<^<<v>>>^<>v^>v>>vv^^<>>v<v<<^<>v>v^<^^^>v^^>v>v>vv<^<v>v^^><<<v<><>^^<>v>v>^^v>v>v^v>>^<v^v>><>^^>^<>>>^vv^><v^<^>v^>^v><^>^^^vv^^v<>vv<>>^><<^v>^v^>>v>^v^<<^^^vv<<vvv>^vv^v<<<v^^<<><vv<>>^^vv>^^^vv>><><v>v<^v^>>>vv^><>><v<^v<>^><v<^^^^>><^<>v>^v<^vv>v>v<^<>v>v>^<vv>v<^>vvv<v^<vv<vv<>v>^><v^v<>>>>>v>><^v<>v>^v><v^v^vv<>^<vvv^>><v^<vvv^^<^vvv^v^<>><v>v^^v<><>v^^^v<<<^><v<<<>><<vv<<><vvv^v>>v^v<v^>>><<v<>^v><>vv<<v>v^vv>v^v<^<vv<><><^v>^<vv>v^^>>^^^><vv<><^>>>^<v^<<^^>^>vv^><v<vvv>^^>>>^><<vv>vv>^<>>^^><^v><<>^<<<v^>^
```

yields 1408 lights on.

To generate input, you may use the following Python script:

```python
import random
length = random.randint(15, 10000)
walk = ''
chars = ['v', '<', '>', '^']
for i in range(length):
    walk += random.choice(chars)
print(walk)
```

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) scoring, winner is the smallest number of bytes.

Comment: 4. 4 lights are on.

Comment: No, there are five.

Comment: So... if you come across a light that is already on? Does it remain on? Edit: what i mean is, can this challenge be summarized as "the number of unique coordinates reached by the given path, starting at 0,0?"

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. You toggle each switch you come across. If you come across one that is on, you turn it off. I can post a couple test cases, if you like.

Comment: Oh, people, don't be so harsh on a newcomer.

Comment: The challenge looks pretty clear (and interesting) to me. Voting to reopen

Comment: Thank you for the reopen. If nobody else answers within the next 10 minutes, I'll post my rather clunky Python solution.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! :)

Comment: I don't see any harshness, just advice on what needs improving, and now the challenge is ready. Nice first challenge!

Comment: Does your script mean that the input length limit is 10000?

Comment: I edited the generator script to make it more idiomatic, feel free to roll back the edit if you want to.

Comment: I don't understand what the output should do. If I input ">>vvv<<", What output will do?

Comment: @Chad : the number of switches in the ON position, at the end. So with your input, the output will be "7".

Comment: Can you confirm if functions are allowed or if our submissions must be complete programs?

Answer (score 28):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 13 bytes

*5 bytes off thanks to @LeakyNun's idea (see [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89972/36398)) of using the imaginary unit as a base for exponentiation.*

```
Jj11\^Ys8#uos
```

Try it online! Test cases: [**1**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=SmoxMVxeWXM4I3Vvcw&input=dj52PF5ePHY8PF48Xj48PD5eXj4-Pjx2PnZ2XnY-dl4-PD48PF4-Pjw8PHZ2dl52dnY-dj4-dj48dnZeXjw8PnZ2Xl4-dl48Pj5eXjxeXj5eXnY8Xj5ePHZ2dl52XnY-PF48PHY8PD4-PDw-dj4-Xj48Xj5eXjw-Pj4-dnY-Xjw8Xjw8Pjx2dnY8dl4-PnZ2dj52Xj4-Pjw8dl4-Xl5eXnY-Pl4-XnY-djx2dl48Pl48PHY-dnY-PjxeXjxePjx2dl5edjx2PHZeXl4-djxednZedjw-PHZ2Xl5ePnZePnY-dnY8PF4-PHY8XnY-PDx2Xl52Pj52PHZ2PD48Xl5edjxedj48Pjw8Xl48Pl4-PjxeXl4-dnZePD4-Pj5ePF48PDw8Pj4-djw8djx2PHZ2Pjw8dnY8dnY8XnZeXl4-PnZ2PD52Pj48PDx2Xj52dj48djw8PHY8PD5ednZ2Xjx2XnY-Xl52XnY-PDx2Xj4-PnY8djx2Xj4-PnY-PD4-Pl48Pjw8PDw-dnY-dj48dj52Pjxedjw-dj4-PnZ2PDw-Xj5ePnY8Xj48XjxednZePjxeXj52PF5edj52XnY8Xl5eXnZ2PD52PD4-PHZeXj48PnY8PDw-dl48dl5ePjw-Xjw-Xjw-Pjw-Xl48Pl52Pjw-Pj48djxeXj4-dj5eXl48dg), [**2**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=SmoxMVxeWXM4I3Vvcw&input=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).

#### Explanation

The code traces the path using unit steps in the complex plane. Then it counts how many times each position was visited, and outputs how many positions were visited an odd number of times.

```
J         % Push the imaginary unit, 1j
j         % Input string
11\       % Modulo 11. This gives 7 6 5 8 for > ^ < v
^         % 1j raised to those numbers, element-wise. This gives -1j for >, -1 for ^,
          % 1j for < and 1 for v. So it gives the displacements in a "transposed"
          % complex plane
Ys        % Cumulative sum. This transforms displacements into positions
8#u       % Count of occurrences of each unique position
o         % 1 if odd, 0 if even
s         % Sum. Implicitly display
```

Comment: [This](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ajExXEp3Xg&input=PD5edg) looks curious

Comment: If you mean the spacing, yes, it's ugly. On Matlab it does look better: `0+1i   0-1i  -1+0i   1+0i`

Comment: No, that was golfing you 3 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, I just realized :-) 13 bytes now!

Comment: Why use `i` instead of `j`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Actually either can be used here. `j` avoids the enclosing quotes, because it considers the input as an unevaluated string

Comment: But you did change from `j` to `i`

Comment: @LeakyNun Because I got confused. When you have something like `11j`, the parser interprets that as the number `11j`. So you'd need `11 j`, or `11i` to avoid that. But in this case it's `j11`, which works fine. So I went back to `j`

Answer (score 19):

## Python, 68 bytes

**25 bytes thanks to Sp3000.**

**2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo's idea of taking modulus with 11.**

**17 bytes thanks to xnor.**

```python
d=set()
p=0
for c in input():p+=1j**(ord(c)%11);d^={p}
print(len(d))
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/NYFa9b)

Comment: It's shorter to use a set doing `d^={p}` and `len(d)`.

Answer (score 8):

## Java 8, <s>169</s> <s>130</s> 127 bytes

Thanks to Leaky Nun for saving <s>29</s> 32 bytes.

```
s->{int l=s.length,d=2*l+1,p=l*d+d,r=0,m[]=new int[d*d];for(char c:s){p+=c<61?-1:c<63?1:c<95?-l:l;m[p]^=2;r+=m[p]-1;}return r;}
```

Ungolfed (sorta):

```
public static int f(char[] s) {
    int l = s.length, d = 2*l+1, p=l*d+d, r = 0;
    int[] m = new int[d*d];
    for(char c : s) {
        p += c<61 ? -1 : c<63 ? 1 : c<95 ? -l : l;
        m[p] ^= 2;
        r += m[p] - 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: `for(char c:s){p+=c<61?-1:c<63?1:c<95?-l:l;m[p]^=2;r+=m[p]-1;}` can be `for(int c:s)r+=(m[p+=c<61?-1:c<63?1:c<95?-l:l]^=2)-1;` to save 8 bytes: [**Try it online.**](https://tinyurl.com/y6blrl7c)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

A port of [Luis Mendo's answer in MATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89961/48934)

```
O%11*@ı+\œ^/L
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TyUxMSpAxLErXMWTXi9M&input=&args=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)

```
O%11*@ı+\œ^/L
O             convert to codepoint
 %11          modulo 11
    *@ı       power of i (imaginary unit)
       +\     cumulative sum
         œ^/  reduce by multiset symmetric difference
            L length
```

Credits of the `œ^/` trick to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78303/48934)

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 49 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`
Run with the control string on STDIN

```
./lights.pl <<< "<<>"
```

`lights.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$\-=1-($a{$x+=/</-/>/,$y+=/\^/-/v/}^=2)for/./g}{
```

If input is restricted to 10000 bytes this reduces to `44+1`:

```
$\+=$#{$x+=/</-/>/.e5+/\^/-/v/}*=-1for/./g}{
```

Answer (score 6):

## TSQL, <s>238</s> <s>235</s> <s>203</s> 191 bytes

Creating a table in memory using recursive SQL. Selecting and calculating from that table(one line code).

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)= 'v>v<';

WITH C as(SELECT 0 a,b=1UNION ALL SELECT
a+POWER(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@,b,1),'> <v')-2,15),b+1FROM
C WHERE b<=LEN(@))SELECT top
1sum(sum(1-1/b)%2)over()FROM c
GROUP BY a OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)= '>>>><^v^v';

WITH C as
(
  SELECT 0 a,b=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a+POWER(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@,b,1),'> <v')-2,15),b+1
  FROM C
  WHERE b<=LEN(@)
)
SELECT top 1sum(sum(1-1/b)%2)over()
FROM c
GROUP BY a
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064558/how-many-lights-are-on)**

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

A port of [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89961/48934).

```
Count[{_,_?OddQ}]@Tally@Accumulate[I^Mod[ToCharacterCode@#,11]]&
```

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##LVHBSsNAFPyVUsGDeOl9fEZ68lBU6E18ZUlSWkgaKNsFEfPrceatIWx2386bmTcZUz71Y8rnNi3H1dOyT8Pw3by07W28DSn3n6@@n7andE1t7q/bqeubu3k3dfNm8zVvp9slzz@Hx8PzW9d9/N4v79fzJTcPx1WzWhcrcEcBHG6AuZsZWC7OhSUWWQJQVCosGl@e2AbBnDAYG0nElXzmFUwG0opcBGoknzA8k6QQp3uRFVDLgj4M6Oh8okdOJAg1yBoBHn4lzyuiZQMuVdSybJnACCBkRjjZJwCi8FrWiCIPWrdQ4uMyJ@9sQKgERXR7KIhdYyH86rqgzqukmALZveYQ81n1apFgKFgoRKqIxStj@NbomkopajTZi/@llPTlTnDFq/@grdj8/xSBmTbaVUklIeNKF2W9/AE) by using [infix notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html)

Answer (score 3):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), 160 bytes

Using the function-as-a-file format:

```
x=0;y=0;a=[];{switch(_x){case"v":{y=y-1};case"^":{y=y+1};case"<":{x=x-1};case">":{x=x+1};};if([x,y]in a)then{a=a-[[x,y]]}else{a=a+[[x,y]]}}forEach _this;count a
```

Call as: `"STRING" call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Ungolfed:

```
//position tracker variables
x = 0; y = 0;
//`a` keeps track of which coords are switched on
a = [];
{
    //switch based on the magic variable `_x`
    //which is the current element of the forEach
    //and adjust coord tracker variables
    switch(_x) {
        case "v": {
            y = y - 1
        };
        case "^": {
            y = y + 1
        };
        case "<": {
            x = x - 1
        };
        case ">": {
            x = x + 1
        };
    };
    //check if the coord is already turned on
    if ([x, y] in a) then {
        //remove it from `a` using array exclusion
        a = a - [[x, y]]
    } else {
        //append it to `a`
        a = a + [[x, y]]
    }
//do this for each character in _this (the argument)
} forEach _this;
//return the length of `a`
count a
```

Comment: easily followed, but how is the performance?

Comment: @zinking That depends on how you execute it. Really fast with a static compile at engine load time, much slower with `compile "CODE"`.

Answer (score 3):

### Python: <s>207</s> <s>189</s> 181 Bytes

```
a = input()
l=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
 if a[i]=='v':y-=1
 if a[i]=='^':y+=1
 if a[i]=='<':x-=1
 if a[i]=='>':x+=1
 if [x,y] in l:l.remove([x,y])
 else:l.append([x,y])
print(l)
```

Input is a string.

Thanks to @LuisMendo for pointing out that I can actually only indent by 1 space. Darn my Python teachers for telling me to ***always*** do it increments of four.

Fixing it so that input was obtained rather than assumed stored actually saved me 8 bytes.

Comment: I don't know Python, but I think 1-space indenting is enough, and it will save you a few bytes

Comment: All these years, I've been making sure to **always** indent at increments of 4.

Comment: But not in code golf :-)

Comment: You can't assume that the input is pre-stored. Just use `input()` and store it somewhere

Comment: If you ever need more than one level of nested indentation, there's a [**great tip**](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/20283) about mixing spaces and tabs

Comment: @LeakyNun Fixed the code so that input was not assumed.

Comment: @CasperTheFriendlyCode You can use tabs instead of spaces, too. A tab is only one character.

Comment: As I only have one level of nesting, tabs would not save any bytes here.

Comment: Which Python? - on 2.7 you'd need to add `x=y=0` before the loop.  Also shouldn't you `print len(l)` for the "how many" aspect?  On the other hand you can do `for b in a:` and then `if b=='v'` etc. That gets you to 165

Comment: Um... Maybe removing the whitespace around the first = and l+=[[x,y]] is also shorter then l.append([x,y]).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 64 + 6 = 70 bytes

+6 bytes for `-rset` flag.

A straight port of [Leaky Nun's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89972/11261).

```ruby
->s{d=Set.new
q=0
s.each_char{|c|d^=[q+=1i**(c.ord%11)]}
d.size}
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/Cnjy

Comment: I believe the `-rset` flag only counts as 4 bytes.

Comment: [With the newest meta changes the `-rset` flag now counts as 0 bytes.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52194)

Comment: @ValueInk Oof. I don’t like that at all. Thanks for the heads-up, though.

Comment: I think they made some pretty good points as to why they want to do this (like how `-e` being "free" in Ruby means `-n` is 1 byte instead of 3 but people who don't know about that could report different bytecounts) but to each their own. BTW, `Set[]` saves 2 bytes over `Set.new`.

Comment: Another thought I had while thinking up a non-`rset` answer: `bytes.map` saves 4 bytes over `each_char` because you can take out the `ord` call.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>97</s> <s>93</s> 85 bytes

```
i=>[...i].reduce((c,d)=>c-1+(v[p+=v['^<>v'.search(d)]]^=2),0,p=1E6,v=[-1E3,-1,1,1E3])
```

EDIT: -8 bytes, thanks to Neil

Test:

```js
var test0 = 'v>v<^^<v<<^<^><<>^^>>><v>vv^v>v^><><<^>><<<vvv^vvv>v>>v><vv^^<<>vv^^>v^<>>^^<^^>^^v<^>^<vvv^v^v><^<<v<<>><<>v>>^><^>^^<>>>>vv>^<<^<<><vvv<v^>>vvv>v^>>><<v^>^^^^v>>^>^v>v<vv^<>^<<v>vv>><^^<^><vv^^v<v<v^^^>v<^vv^v<><vv^^^>v^>v>vv<<^><v<^v><<v^^v>>v<vv<><^^^v<^v><><<^^<>^>><^^^>vv^<>>>>^<^<<<<>>>v<<v<v<vv><<vv<vv<^v^^^>>vv<>v>><<<v^>vv><v<<<v<<>^vvv^<v^v>^^v^v><<v^>>>v<v<v^>>>v><>>>^<><<<<>vv>v><v>v><^v<>v>>>vv<<>^>^>v<^><^<^vv^><^^>v<^^v>v^v<^^^^vv<>v<>><v^^><>v<<<>v^<v^^><>^<>^<>><>^^<>^v><>>><v<^^>>v>^^^<v';
var test1 = '>>><^>>>^vv><^^v^<<<>>^<>>^<^>^<<^^v^<v^>>^<<><<>^v<^^^vv>v><^>>^<^<v><^v<^<<^^v><>>^v<^>^v<vvv<<<v^vv>>^vv>^^<>>vv>^<^>vv<>v^<^v<^^<v^^^<<^><><>^v>vvv<^vvv<vv><vv<^^v^^<^^>>><<<>^<>>><^<<<>><>^v><^^vv<>>><^^^<^>>>>v<v^><<>v<v<v^<<^><v^^><>v>^<>^^^vvv<v^>^^^^v>v<v>>>v^^<v<vv>><<>^vv><<vv<<>^^v>>v<^^v>><v<v<<>^^vv>>^v>v>v<>^>^v<>>><>v>v<<v<^<>>>vv>>v>^<>vv^v><><^v^>v<^^>v<^v>>v^>^>>v>v>^>^<^^>vv>>^vv<^><>^><<v^<><<^<^>^^vv^<<^^<^^v<v<>^>v>>>>>>vv<<v>^>vv^>^><^<^^><<vvvv>vvv<><<><v^vv><v^^<>^>><^vv<><>^>vv>>>vv^vv<<^v^^<<v^^>^>vvv<><<v>^>^>v<v>^<^^^^<^>^>><>>^^vv<>v<^>v><v<v^>>v<^v<vv>v^>v<v^<^^^^v<^<^<<v<<<v<v^^>vv^>><<<v>>^^^>^<^>>>v^v><^^vv^>><^^vv<vv<v^><>>^><<<>>^^v^v<<v^<vv^^^>><>>^v^^^>>^>^<<^>v>^^v>><>v>^>vv^^<vvvv<><^v>^><<>>><^<^v^<<vvv^v<<<<<><><<><><<v>v<v>v><^v^^vvv>><>^>^>^v<<vv^^^v^vv><v><><v<v<<>>>v<^<^v<<>^v<<^v<><>v>>^^>^<v^<<^v^^^vv>><v^<v>^v><^<>>>>^^<vv<>^^>^>v^v^^>><>^^<^v^<v<<v<^<<^^vv>v>^<vv<<^^v^vv^>^^<>v>^>^<>vv><v>>><<><<vv^^<vv<>>^v>^<<vv>^><<>^<v>v><<v^<v<><v>^<^<^><^^^^>>>^<>^^><>>v^<vv^<^<<vvvv>>>v^v>>^>v^><<>>v<>>^>><vvvvv<<vvvv<v>^v<vv^<>><<><v^^<^<v>^v<^<<>^v<v^<>v<<>^<<vvv><^><^^^<>>v^<<>vv><^^^>><^>v^v>v<v^>>v>>v>vv<<v<<vvv^^^>^<v^^<^<v<^<>>v^<<v>>v^><v<vvvvv^^^<v^^<><v<<^>>^><^<v^v^^>><v><>v>^<vvvv><<v^^v^>^>v>><>^^v>v^>vv^>v<^<<^vv^>vv^<v>^<v^<>^v>v^>v^<<>^^<^>^^>vv^>>vv>v>vvv><>^v<<<<v^>v^^v<><v<v>^<^><^><<v<>><<>v^^>>><<><>>><<>><v^^>><^>><^<>v^^vvv>v<^<<vv^>vv^><<>v><>^<>v^^v>^>v^<>^><v>^><<^v<v^^<v>><^^>>^<^<^v<v>^>^<^<v><><>>>><>^<^<v>v<v^>v><>v^>v^<<><^<>>v<^vv^^^>^<<<<>^>^<><^vvv>^^<v^v>v>v^v>v>>vv>^><>^vv>^<v<v^<>vv^<v<><>^>>vvv><>>^<<v^<<>^<v^>v<^^^<^<^^<>^>>v>^<v>vv<v^^>><<<<<>>v>^v>^>>>>v>>^^>^<<<^<<<v>>^><<<<^vv<<>^v<^>v^<v<<>v<>^<^<^<^<>>^^^vvv<v>^vv>^><^<v^>^v<v>><><vvv<^^>>v<^v>^>>>><v^<v^^<^^v<vvv<v>^^<<>><^<v^v<^vv>v>vv>^^<>^^^^>>^v><vv<<<v>^v^>>v^>><<<^v^v<<>><<vvvvv<v^vv>vvvv><v^v<^^^><vv^^<>><>><^>^^^^v>v><><v^<>^v<>^^<^^>^^^vvv>>vv^v^<v<vv^v>v>>>^v^^vv^<^v>v^v>>^v>v<v^<^^><vvv>><<>><>><v>v<^<v>>>>v^^v^^>^><<v><^<<>>v<>^^<<>vv^>>vv^^^v>>>^v^><v<<^>v<v><>>>^>>^<<>>^><<vv<^^>^^^v^^<>>>vv><<>v<><<<>v<<>>>v<>v<>^<vv^v<^^<<<v>^v>>^^>^><<^vv<><><>v>^v>^<>v>>^^^<^^>>vv>v<<<v^><<v><^v><>v<^<<^<>^vv>^><^^^^^<<v^^<>v>><^<v^^^vv>^v<>^<v<v>v>^><^<<^<>><^^>vv^<>^<>vv<>>v<vv^>><^^<^>v<><>vv<v<>>v><v^^^>^^^<<vv^><^^v>v>^<^>v^><<vvv>v^><vv<><^<><^>^v<><<v^<<><>^^^^<<^>>^>^v^>v>^<<^>vv^vv^v<>^<<^>v<^^<<v<v<<<^>vv^>><>v>><><v>v><v^><vvv>vv<<vvv>v^<<^v<^<><<^v>v<>>vv<<v^>v>v<<>>^vv^<^^^<^v>>^<vv>^<v>><>v>^^<<v^<>>>>>v^v>><>v^>>^<>>^<^vvv^^^<^v<><vvv^>^>v><<v>>^v>v<v>v^<v>v>^<>vvv>vvv^^<>vv>^^^^^>v<<^v<>>>><<<>>><vv>>^v^^v<v^>>>^>^v<^v>^v<>vv<><vvv^v<<<<v<vv>vv^<^vvv<^v>v^^vv<^>>>^^>>^^><>^>>v<>>>^^<<v<^<<<<<^^<v^^^<<>><<<^>^v^>vv<>>>^^v><<>^^^^<vvv><^^<>>>^><<^>><v>^<>^v^<vvvv^>>^><<>><^<v^>>vv^vv<^>>>><^>^v<^<v<^^<^<^><^<>>^<>v^v<<>v>v<>><<v<^v<<<^v<v<>><v<^<^>>v>v>><v^<v><>>>>>v^v>><^<^<v>><v^v>v<>v<v><<<>^^><>^^<^vv^^<>v><><><^>^^v^vv^<><>>>>v><>>^>^<<^<v<v^>v^^<v>>><<^^vv^^>><<^<vvvvv>><^>^>>^vv<><<>v>v^<<<^v<^^<<^vv>v<vvv><^v>vv^vvvv<^>^v^<<<<^v<<<>^vvv>^v><<>>v<v<^v^<>v>>^^v^vv>>>^v^^>>^<><><<<<^vv>>>>>v>v^>v<>><<<>^vv>^^^^<^^^>^^^^>^^^v^v><^>^>>>v<v<^<^^<<^v<<^<>vvv^^^^v^<<>vv>^^>>><^^v<^<<<v<>v<<><>v<><>^<v<<^>^^>><<v>^^><^^v<^<v^<^^<>^<>^v^>>^^v^v^<>v<>^<<<>^v^v>^<vvvv<>v<<>vv^<<>vv>>>>^<v><>>>v^><<>^v>><<>>^^v><^<>>vv^^^>vv^<^^v><v>>vvv^v<^v>v<<^^<>v^^^v^^>><v^>>v^v^vv<^>v^<^>^>v<v^><vvv^>^<>v<<^><^^<vv>v>>vv>v^>>^vvv>>v^>^^>vvv>>v><<>>^^v>v<v<><<<<^^v<^<>^v>><v^^^<>>vvv>v><<v>^^<^vvvv^v>v>^vv>^vv^^v><<>>^^>>v>>>^v><^>v<^^<>vv>v>v^^^>>^^^><<<<>>^>>^<^v<^<^<>^><v<<v>v<>^>>^<<v^^<v^vvvvv>>v^>>^^^<^^<><<><><>^v>vvv^>^^>v<^^>^<<^v^^^><>><<v<^^^<<<<>><>><<^^v><v^<<^v<v><<>^<v>^>^v>vv>><v^<^<v<v<v><^^^^>>><^<><^v^v<<<^>vv^<v^>^^v^>>><<<<^<>>><v>>>vv^>^^<v^v>>>v^<^<>vv>^v^^><<<v>v>v>><>>>v<^>^<>>^^<v^<<^<v^>><^v^><><v><><v^vvv<<>v>>><<><v>v<>>><^<^^v<v>^<<>^v>^>^>^^<^^><^>>>>><^^>vv>^<^^<><^>^<^^><^<v>v^>><^>^^^>>v^v<^>>^<v^<>^><><v>>^v<v^^^^v<^vv><^v>>^^^<>^<^<^>vv^v<<>vv>^<>v>^>^>vv^v<vv<^^^v<v>v>v^<^^^v><v<<<^^<><^^>>>><<^^v<<^>v<<vv^^^vv^vv^<v><>^v<v>>><vv^v<v^>>>>^<<<vv^>>v>^><<><<^<^><<vv^>v^>><>v^<<<>v^><>><<>>v><>v^<v><>^v>>><><>>>^vvv^v>vv>>>^^v^><<v<>>^^^v^^><<^v<><><v<<v<v<><<<v^<^^^<>v^^v<^^<<^>v<<v><^<<<<>><>^v>^<>^<^^v^vvv>^^<>^>><v^^vv^<>^<><<^^^v<^^^>>^^v>^>^<^>v><<^<>^v<><vv^vv<><<<<<<v<<v<<vv^<<^<^vvvv><v^v^v<>>>vvvvv^<vv^<^<>vv>^<><<v><>v^^<v<>>>vvv^><^<^>v^^<v>^<>>>^^v^<vv<<<<^><v<<<>v<<<v<>>^^^>^><>v>^v^>^<v^^><^v^^<^v^^>^v>>^^^<<><><<<>v>><^><>>>vvvv>v>>v>^^^^v<><vv<^<v^v>>^^vv<^>vvv>^v>>><v<v<v^<^>^^<vvv<vv<v>>^vv>^<<^<^<v>v^<vv^^^v>vv<v><v><v>^<v>>vv<>v>^^>v^^^<>v<>v^v<>^<><v><^>^<v^v><<^v^v^v<<v><<^^<^vv>^<^v><>v>><v^v^>><><><<<v<>v<^vv>v<v<<>^vvvvv^<<<^<vv><<><>v^<^v<<<^>v>v<v^<<^>v<<^<v><<<^>vv>v>^<^^v>>>><>vv>>vv>vvv<>^^<>^v^<>vvv<^^^vv>v><<<<vv^v><v^<^<<<><v<>^><<>^>v<^^<<>v>>v<<>><^^<<<^<^vv^^>v>v<>^^>>^v^vvv>^v^>v>>v>v>v>>vv^<><<<<>v^^>vv<^^v>>v<vv<^>>^<>^^v<><vv^<><v><v<<v^v<^^<^v^v<>v<<><vvv><<<^<^^<<>>^v>>>^v>>>v<>>^><<<><><<<v<vv<^<>v^^v^^>^<<^^^v^>^<<^>^>^>>>>v<v<v<>vv<<vv^<<^<vv>^^<^<<>><^v><><>^<v><v^>^v>^<^>^^><v><<^<v^^<<^><><v>v<>>><<^><v<^vvv^<<<>><<>^v^^><vv>vv<>^>^>vv<>v^<^<>vv><<>^<v<vv<^<^<><^vv<<^>>>v<>><<>>>^^^^<<^v>>v<vv>^^>v<v<vv^><<><>>>v>>^^v<^v^^>>v^<>>v^>><^<^^v<v<><<><>>^<>><^v<^^^^><>^>vv>>^vv<<>v<<<<<<><<<><<>><v><^^^<>>v<^><^vvv<>^>^^v>^<v><^v^vv^<<>v<<<<v>^vv>>v>vv<<^>^<>>vvv^<v<><>><>^^^^vvvvvvv<<>v<^><^^>vv^^<v<<^^<vvv<v<v<<>><<><v^^>><^<>^v^vv<<v<v<>><<>>>>>^vv<><v<>v><v>v>><v<v^vvvvv<><>v>>v<><<<^^<>^<^^<v>v^<vv>^vv^<>^<<^<vv><v<v>>v>^<>v^<<v^<v>^v<>><v>>>>^<<^^^v<^<>><^<><v>>vv^>^<^<^>>v^>^^^^>vvvvv>^v<^><^^<^^>^<^^^^^^^>v>>vv>v^^^v^^^<>v><^>>>v>^>^>^>vv<vv<^^>>^>>>v<>v><<^<<v^>^>>>>^^><^^<v<<<<>>v>v^v^^<>><v<^<<<<v^^^^<v<<<^>v>^^<vv<^^^^^v>^v^<v><>>^^>^v>^>^vv^v>v>v^>v>^>>^^^^>>^>>^><>><v>v>>><<^v^v^>^>^>>vv><<^>v<v<v^<<>>^v<<^v<<^><^>>^<v>^>vv>v>^^^>v^^<^<^^>vv>^^><v>>^v>^v<<^^^<<^v^>^<<^>vv^>>^<^v><<>v><^^^<^^>>vv>^vv>><^<<<^>vv^v>v<^<<<^<^<<><^^>>>v^<^^^>^<><^v>>^<<v<^v>>v^<^<^<^^^<v^><<vvv^<^v^vv^vv<v<<v<^<>^v>^^^<^^v<v<v><<<^<>^^^^v>v^v^v^v<v><v>>^v><vv^^^v>><<v^vvvv<<<^v<<><^>^<v^^v<>vvvv^vv<>^v<><>^^<>>vvv<^>><v^<<>v>v<>^v^>v^>><<>>^^<^v<>>^>^><>>^<v<v^^<^v><v^<v<><><^<<><v^v<<>vv<v<v<^>>><>vv^^<><<v<^^<<^<><^^^>^>>>^<^>>>^>><^^^<^v^^^v^v^v>v>v><vv>><vvv<<v><><^^>^v<v>><v><^><^<<>v^vv^v><^vv>^>>v<vv><^<^^v<^^vv<vv<v<v>v><v<vv<<>^^v^^v<<<^<>v^^^<><>>><^>v^^^v^vv<<<^>>v><^>v^<>>>>^<>^^vvv^^<><^>^^<><>^vvv^^<vv^>vv^^^^v<>vv<^^^v<<>><<vvvvv>v>^^^vv>><v><v<>vvvv<v^><^<>^>^<>v>v>v^vvvv<><^v>>>^^>><vvv<>^>^v^<vvv>v^vv^vv><>><>v^^v^vv<^v>vv>>v<v><^<<^v<>>^vv^<v>v><v>v>^v>^<v>^<<^>vv>v<^<^vv^<^><<<v<<^^vv<vvv><>v>v<vv^<><><^vvv>>vv<^^^v><^v><<^>^^v>^<>><v<>>^^<<<v><>^>^><vvvv<>^<<<><<<^<>>v^vv^>><^vv^^>^<v^<v>><^^>>>^v>^v<>^v<><^><vv>v^^^<^>>^<<^<^><<<^^<v<<^vv<^<>v<^<<^^<v<vv<<><v<v^<>^<>v>>v<^v>v<>^^vvv<>vv^v^<><v^vv^<^v^v><>^><v^<>>^^^<>>vv^<v>^^v><v<^>^^^^^^><>>vvv<<><><v<^>v<>v^v<<<<>v^>>>>^v>^^<v^>v><v^<^^v<<<<v<<<>^v<^>^v>v^^>v^^vvv>vv<>^>v><v<>^<vv><>>><<^>>><<v>v^^<^<<<<v^<>>>v<<<^v^vv<>^v>v<<<<>^^>><v><>v<v><^^>><>^>^>v>>><v>^vvvv<><><^>>^v^><<>^v<><><^><<<>v^^>v>^>v^<v^vv<>><^vv^^>^^><vv<<>v>v^^>><v^>^<^<>>>vv<>^>v>v^<>v<^<<v>>>^<>v^>v>>vv^^<>>v<v<<^<>v>v^<^^^>v^^>v>v>vv<^<v>v^^><<<v<><>^^<>v>v>^^v>v>v^v>>^<v^v>><>^^>^<>>>^vv^><v^<^>v^>^v><^>^^^vv^^v<>vv<>>^><<^v>^v^>>v>^v^<<^^^vv<<vvv>^vv^v<<<v^^<<><vv<>>^^vv>^^^vv>><><v>v<^v^>>>vv^><>><v<^v<>^><v<^^^^>><^<>v>^v<^vv>v>v<^<>v>v>^<vv>v<^>vvv<v^<vv<vv<>v>^><v^v<>>>>>v>><^v<>v>^v><v^v^vv<>^<vvv^>><v^<vvv^^<^vvv^v^<>><v>v^^v<><>v^^^v<<<^><v<<<>><<vv<<><vvv^v>>v^v<v^>>><<v<>^v><>vv<<v>v^vv>v^v<^<vv<><><^v>^<vv>v^^>>^^^><vv<><^>>>^<v^<<^^>^>vv^><v<vvv>^^>>>^><<vv>vv>^<>>^^><^v><<>^<<<v^>^';

S=i=>[...i].reduce((c,d)=>c-1+(v[p+=v['^<>v'.search(d)]]^=2),0,p=1E6,v=[-1E3,-1,1,1E3])

console.log(S(test0))
console.log(S(test1))
```

Comment: Use `[...i]` instead of `i.split('')`. Also, I think you can write `(p=1E6,v=[-1,1,-1E3,1E3],0)` as `0,p=1E6,v=[-1,1,-1E3,1E3]`.

Comment: If you can arrange for the `^` to be first, `search` saves a byte over `indexOf`. (You need the `^` to be first because `search` treats `^` as a regexp metacharacter.)

Comment: You don't have to count the `S=` part.

Comment: @Arnauld No, the argument name(s) itself is/are part of the function and should remain. However, assigning the function to a variable ("`S=`") is optional (as you can just call the function like `(«function code here»)(«argument»)`).

Answer (score 2):

## R, <strike>172</strike> <strike>156</strike>  <strike>137</strike>  <strike>101</strike> 96 bytes

```
n=function(a)sum(table(cumsum(sapply(strsplit(a,"")[[1]],switch,v=-1,"^"=1,">"=1i,"<"=-1i)))%%2)
```

Using @LeakyNun's complex plane idea.

ungolfed

```
n=function(a){
    b=strsplit(a,"")[[1]]                        #Splits String up
    p=sapply(b,switch,v=-1,"^"=1,">"=1i,"<"=-1i) #Replaces characters with directions
    q=cumsum(p)                                  #Finds each location visitied
    t=table(q)%%2                                #Determines if spots were visited an odd # of times
    sum(t)                                       #counts odd visited spots
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

This is a port of [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89961/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZGxTUNBEER7seQGEBmjlRtAUMFKllOHeCVCROqQLxICEAVQAgE59HCNfM/b4@vr/t3e7Mzs/P3h4bQ/Hh/X9W6c36/vd9ufr/H0Pc4ft3/PN2N5HcuLL8bydrjabSn/fq7rpqKUqZJSGVJkRoRcrvTikosuSSpK5WL49cltApaGKdxoIq/mi5xgM5gWcghoNB8Yn01SxnEPWcla0fRtgGP66R6cICgasGZAtl/kfWU0NpSoapaxFYDVQGEGHPYNEBQ5y4wIedNmtJKfxBze3aBWaYruzlaAnbHUfrkuzXlJyimYPWcOPV9Mr9EJtkK0QqeqXnIytm9GZypSZDTs9f8iJb7eASde/gNb2PL/1IEFG3ZTkiQwTrqqzQU)

**Edit:** One byte thanks to Leaky Nun.

```
O⌠4P@%ïⁿ⌡Mσ;╗╔⌠╜c2@%⌡MΣ
```

**Ungolfing:**

```
O        ord(c) of the input string (implicit input)
⌠...⌡M   Start a function, and map over the list of ord(). Call the variable i.
  4P@%     i mod 11 (the 4-th prime).
  ïⁿ       1i to the power of (i%11).

σ        Push a list of cumulative sums of the new list of complex numbers.
           This is a list of the coordinate visited.
;╗       Duplicate coord_list, and push to register 0.
╔        uniquify(coord_list)

⌠...⌡M   Map over the uniquified list. Call the variable j.
  ╜c       Push coord_list.count(j)
  2@%      Push count mod 2

Σ        Return the sum of this last list.
```

Comment: Other than writing `:11` as `4P`, I am unable to come up with any golf advice

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 136 bytes

```powershell
$a=@();switch -w($args|% t*y){'^'{$y++}'>'{$x++}'v'{$y--}'<'{$x--}*{if("$x,$y"-in$a){$a=$a|?{$_-ne"$x,$y"}}else{$a+="$x,$y"}}};$a.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVGLbsJADPsVhG4qj3U/gMn2JZmqqQOkik20OkCl397ZObQKlZzPcRz39@faXvpj23XznJr9x2q966@n4eu4qK@r1FwO/eNlMWzu67Hyakz37XaqjMVNRRZS11MFISw24@l7tUy313Rf1qdzatYjRVPzeB/TZ31un1fT1HZ9y6vt/h@Zdql569rzYTjO85wtwx0ZcLgB5m5mIJydL0IECQHIgjJB448ntkE0Jw3GRgrxTT3zQqYCZSUuATVSTxyeKZLJ073EMjjLQj4M6Oh8okdONBBqkDUSPPxqPK/Ilg24pqLAsmUiI4iQGfFknwRIwgusFSUesm4xiY/LnLyzATElJKLbY4LUtRbCr64zyr5KiilQ3UsOsZ8VrxYJxgSLCZEq4uVFMXxrdW2lFLWa7MX3Ukr6ZyW64tV3UCk1f54iMFOhqoxUEjKudJH/AA)

I think there's more to optimize here, but this is the lowest I got for now.

Easier to read:

```powershell
$a=@();switch -w($args|% t*y){
    '^'{$y++}
    '>'{$x++}
    'v'{$y--}
    '<'{$x--}
    *{if("$x,$y"-in$a){$a=$a|?{$_-ne"$x,$y"}}else{$a+="$x,$y"}}
};$a.length
```

**Explanation:** The input is changed to a character array and each piece is matched to one of the first 4 switch cases to increment the x or y coord. Everything matches the 5th case where we decide if a light is turned on or off. Length at the end determines total number of switches turned on.

Note: The comma in the coordinates is necessary so we don't get collisions like (10,10) and (101,0)

Comment: Strip some apostrophes and pull $x,$y into a variable for [127bytes](https://tio.run/##LVGLbsJADPsVhG6ihXU/gMn2JZmqqQOkik0UHY/Sb@/s3KrqmuQcx3F/f67deTh0fT/Pqd19VPV2uB4vX4dFc61Se94Pz5fFZX2vRx/TfbOZVrYa041BZt400wrKGazH43dVpcdumW6v6b6sm@MptfVI1tQ@38f02Zy69Jimrh86Vjc7JdM2tW99d9pfDvM8Z8twRwYcboC5mxlYzs6DJRZZApBVyiwaX2Zsg2BOGIyNJOJJPvMCJgNpRS4CNZJPGOYkycTpXmQZnGVBHwKUOp/okRINhBokjQAPvRrPK6IlA66pKGXJMoERQEiMcJJPAEThpawVRR60bjGJj0uctLMBMSUoottjgti1FkKvrjPKvnKKLpDdiw@xnxWtFg7GBIsJ4Sri8MIYurW6tpKLWk3y4n/JJX0ZCS579R8Uis3/szDMFCgqI@WEhMtd5D8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: `-ne` works with array [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##LVEBboNADPtKVd3U0pZ9YG6eEglNrK2Euqmgo5TxdmbnhtCR5BzHMT/fY/vor23XrWs/3obP66Ye96l5XPrft81wmKrZ5zQdj8vOdnN6MsjM63rZQTmDw3z72u/T67xNz1OatlV9u6emmlNzTk19b9Nrabu@ZX48n5gsy0dq3rv2fhmu67pmy3BHBhxugLmbGVjOzoMlFlkCkFXKLBpfZmyDYE4YjI0k4kk@8wImA2lFLgI1kk8Y5iTJxOleZBmcZUEfApQ6n@iREg2EGiSNAA@9Gs8roiUDrqkoZckygRFASIxwkk8AROGlrBVFHrRuMYmPS5y0swExJSii22OC2LUWQq@uM8q@cooukN2LD7GfFa0WDsYEiwnhKuLwwhi6tbq2kotaTfLif8klfRkJLnv1HxSKzf@zMMwUKCoj5YSEy13kPw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [Length -> Count for 114](https://tio.run/##LVGLboNADPuVqrqp0Jb9wNx8SiRUsbVSRafCrg/GtzM7N4SOJOc4jvm@3rvbcOoul2UZ7ufxeFo19yq1t6/h9201bp/15FN67nbzxjZTejDIzJtm3kA5g@10/qyq9Dqs02Ofnuu6OfeprafUHlLb9F16zd1l6JjvDnsm8/yR2vfj9acfl2XJluGODDjcAHM3M7CcnQdLLLIEIKuUWTS@zNgGwZwwGBtJxJN85gVMBtKKXARqJJ8wzEmSidO9yDI4y4I@BCh1PtEjJRoINUgaAR56NZ5XREsGXFNRypJlAiOAkBjhJJ8AiMJLWSuKPGjdYhIflzhpZwNiSlBEt8cEsWsthF5dZ5R95RRdILsXH2I/K1otHIwJFhPCVcThhTF0a3VtJRe1muTF/5JL@jISXPbqPygUm/9nYZgpUFRGygkJl7vy/Q8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```powershell
$(switch -w($args|% t*y){^{$y++}'>'{$x++}v{$y--}'<'{$x--}*{"$x,$y"}})|group|% c*|%{$r+=$_%2}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZnrbhVZDoX/5ykidJgQLtJMa0ZqjYw1T@LWiElfJKSmE9qAQp6dKa9vuWhA4ZxK1d7evqy17Prw@6e7@4df796//3b5@frt9eO3y4uHT799fPfr9ZtPLy7/vf/l4evz648vv9w@1uPly6tXTzd583j5fHzo4/ubN083Md@PDy8fn10@v758efb0dPv1l/vf//xwPPnu5dfnj5f7V28vPz3/4enqcv/t6erqPy@uro8/r1/844d/vb7p7KiKjqiojMiqzIzjctfx47h0XDwuRUTPpT4u5vHv@HY8FnNbHbdFHg8eCx0/j/WyuPlY4Vh2Fp8F5sFjvbnn@H4s0sd98/tZrOPYK7W8DJivdfzRM2PJbBjzwJh23FCyd7Y/fnXcPWZEza7B5TEr5@bQjTHGzH1j/nFDzBLF5TniLK5lK7XT8afGuLH9eCC0i5bQ06UdZvU5Vsje@XUH5x1PHV44Vi/8oPMltqY8qB1SO8iroR/FirJ7jj6nGi/O0cY8xWu8NP8fn@b2ce/EYT7OauVvcljOh/nEluOJMXy8G31zu8nwz7//@Ppmfj/W1RxlDNfxFV1FlWtzAIVtFpUXsRyPcQbunR1JiFaMxwsTvfmhLFAOFG4sPSfbSzFLGd3yduP91ulJNbldxinLOCh2NxeVI3hduY33yQfcJRdVOf9IuOPjPKOqUKoF/ghCQgLpPyWFLulMk22KGdvr67g7SHZ2U11N8jWhVNbOdqmo9Dyvy7hJfiilj9JU5dM6xNw2BkyOZKZzZhZorRZaR3WLF1OlprP0me@6nuwn46ZeVNvjotoH27moeOHYeTxzU7CUwVRxKNyqv7G7KDRDAdUqG1U3s4TOLKc7fpQipSYQkg/YrlreoMbJMH0iQZXZjfu1i7BI5d5ahHRRbgukQhWIc3TQ3kJUXiirCCpb2oFzM@HXgefIKgcVMFgnHCzcqRSR2eQoAFMCIvw8d7lWVWSkTri6dGewOwhKpgA6qoXEQC05m@iAHLk4kvYfu1WoghPVkYpgPIlbo5w0BETGyXFaOAXXSjWVDbVdQLwSi0MK2UsJkPKNHkhvy2aYTxzlgnQGpZGbXcqu1NKxz1I1KlLuIavFZTBNrFPbta5TwQJF2VDQTT7i8OabvNQAZxfWkvdOXsVFCyZZpLvgH1ysw0ab/QxZoPBCtmBzjuRsa5zPFuJMQZx4C6ItxS@VaAq3SgXsrQ4DCAmawiG@yrNyhA@DI3Ve@TcgHFUK@NxgWsH52hXoDofV@ZSmbvFE4KkwvskswKbJw/bB4VbVAyjtkpEmiHbJC6EgmqQsBLLB3zzRG8MIutIu08KiDEnsEu1MMiXpoJHOlihHFcoEV@AdYaDijvEAURpgG2AlwUzOFknCqDjZRWYpreLUTACNJJPyGY8nEDRhdSH2AqpO5jRCrinG8BbAHYH6UtmuVtMmwkedhVrpsBqB1nm217Ja/sLzEhhGPSLRHNcOIogZyyzhCBsSYW4lesDKglpJF6nBM45iGUq6HR5hYbFpwJV@CGWEQpSaQDCuTgSSRZYJ@@lsVBp6Ch1ivgRYmhpBvqQTm6wwxIjETTtt8ck3OUT8EMt16ZTEAiJoGE1oIuB4yQh@VYgISYGimsaNQRGa5ag5FICpr07VZmi0LDbsUV6mOshBflMCF6yiAKQJzWJL2O@8RMfKN0VUevcADSUBGhNIYfSMMgTCKTiFI6C2vytAqgwf@66mQ4HTFdskXQF5ZQ8oDwNsXa@yAQGwWULYNIjIpaDxvuxR9MgamWeFZh7/q8eB2AQxg4oKs2oh3gswJ5/gcSM0wEkz1GYRc7rqX3jDsRrzkYbwg0S6K1AQZN/Qwsn3iZLnQAm6txldrYyLE3GekGahh1gUMwXplt3OkHApGSva5rGwbVKFkoe1pA8ZogtFka3agk2AJc6tW31jm0oCINaGZRSSTbUkz3q9u0njEDFotQyetWLMHaN2QFGRyIqndkX7KdFEAk6oRgr3ljSiLJA50UudTcys9CWrFXjboCQj@xsQRB9gmsWbM8n0ABa2iyJp6mAr448VCiRWsKlR3no8oQD3LWm8JW0w1ZC98tgNGUcI6Br5vTVT7pnD6ZuWwNErROnnXUZFY31KUQAXCLEMo1xAIIRzuFdZjSI9aNRqDtquVNR5ekDR1BiNT4HG7okofYvY7G0TUFRkjNoA2FdAYtJJO8iNG2KrlvKTVj1XTLIpwtgDCKpVnrYwb0OReZM@rBg8YJLqvvAvoIkKtNfhIDcsYI11agPii9@qHIQBgLmDIGlQaKsYKhDStIb0ehKYwcigHVfihfB10WxbFJ6kMDGhERCZVK3JGWcGoRvKbY81GYWxXB@e4pDjFr8qF0usAPmRm7EthfKgTrUGxdFHuAOy84PeQcMAbqGxNkaXeYn2zJMmFNIePz1oaPcwdJaBSnPYDbUInVxbaIPIEkYfZLt51DDuMQQ4VGjajh2yhKlpG2b0d/KvwDlERAI3DQ/q7KB5ML@qduvNtIzVUW4QX5EKC@fmIhNOQ1OM0HKnPfTrO5QRUXS68pFkOmAC4jvGKPM8o6EdP5HHbVRRGYe7X8sx@RNNgDGQK@gnfDY1lhtQsPsc0qna4/sEsdw5O8twmFQb0kJ@bM83kx0R2Abq7ah3ABEsG6eIJ7s92KjcYVYgtjaPqQx3MWgM@VGNULplJW7C9zAIAXI7HW1P@yBSkZlyA/CJ7xAb1t@mEBq08mGCgoD48RNcgR53@0sSUwNMjwHMnWhxG7qeOec5o6IdZGpD0dBLn1MFMW/bcgQBjIIYCPcp54gBcuizl7XC7/aUwyvuLAmB2r3DHw89YC5EQXScrlilpiILq8dlWA@KQCej/1msuRjnqlFNQwgIfkQ3ZLip4l4orGDKfJIebgJxNNPh5pNOq@oUKso91CqT6toccDPtWJNQ0c7LsuLZtr7dOq6wb3R77IzOZKYQrZ4GEktHbwvORISwb227S@Y2c5xyf1rnhDd3FMcQxroDUAHqYqes1EbSw4Qzt86mLo1y@ON7/8pAr1ameHLDlNNU3FbHYX6np7BYgfy24SxnqPIqVgLWOeM1fOwMwVjca/lie4ZTy2J/8ZvuzEwIE6@0pHWqbXxqad9vdAAoJrBMbsMYC5@XZ8rh/poei/dCYUUYwESRKEx6a@fzHqkSbtpLXhUwJT9nOZ4cCofBeQYFQIyh4xwZu8s@R/YF2YRJDnWXO85VEMn389WPWLZX2BXa1/NVsMBepe6@D4JIsbbNdnwgGzyypTrOqTTiPRaz6GB9zAaR2oZaYbVlEuFpt/D08SBeLYma5gJVHOui9vsJd6GxEyhrShjf@KkapklH9SWtzvZdluW9c/vuHX3vbNLVReqZWvx2plZw7mtIMyCz7w2hB45lvCxzNp0eXWB0bR3xysRvJd3dBe8FlKAGPBeAdWmt9LHatdXlsSmdoTVk7FstRIFHt34VE56K5dIrbSyYEzuraY8Qm54qPC7wrBo@23cPiLzclAHRtpH1hVOhMCZm5TMYjLMYF7iFrX0xhdW9Tu/0MMTqpzwmiIqz6/BOOjOE5fQysLTfwuzcMjyXAg1JWVyaiJTwFHRrylOdnbgywOB1Z7S5kQmi3x/7TdRZep6J8q7VvYsmOrS8VUvZsCGdcqzpQeUkletXvnRI7hUSrd4eb0ZvLJkBgJDd7tiL9yO97wdAnr/0C/t2kfEZPeO@CPerWzCRKTPTEId@7T3bfHAlc18/uX30qxJGL/COmxy428oORr@5vbq9/nr9/PpRL4gvd58/3L37ePe/15eH67fXl5@4en/38Of7j8eFv11@vr486OKzywtff3P3x/nc7b/37mdXT9/@Dw)

Unrolled:

```powershell
$plane=$(switch -w($args|% toCharArray){
    ^  {$y++}
    '>'{$x++}
    v  {$y--}
    '<'{$x--}
    *  {"$x,$y"}
})
$plane|group|% count|{$result+=$_%2}
$result
```

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>112</s> 109 bytes

A port of [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89961/48934).

```powershell
$args|% t*y|%{($p+=($c=[numerics.complex])::Pow($c::new(0,1),$_%11))}|group{'{0:N2}'-f$_}|% c*|?{$r+=$_%2};$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZndbhzXEYTv@RQLYxWSNh1IQgwETLOTJwhyH6QFg1nZAWSLIaWWA5LPrsypr3poSaC4szPn9Omfquqeu49fTvcPP58@fPh6fH@4OTx@Pf54/9PD06vDp2//9/Tq8eJ4993NxfH25p@/fv7ldP@f24c/3n785e7D6bd/XV5f/@Pjl@276@tfT18uXl@9ubw6vnv15s3l5fPTT/cfP989nj@@vv772@fz798f3z1va95@@/TXx@P9dzfbfW@f/3K8//p8dva3i7PD9ufq4s3bH67OOzuqoiMqKiOyKjNju9y1/dgubRe3SxHR61JvF3P7t33aHot1W223RW4PbgttP7f1srh5W2Fbdi2@FlgPbuute7bP2yK93be@X4t1bHullpcB62Ntf/TMsmRtGOuBZdp2Q8netf321Xb3MiNq7RpcXmblujl0Yyxj1n3L/O2GWEsUl9cR1@JatlI7bX9qGbds3x4I7aIl9HRph7X6OlbI3vV1B@ddntq8sK1e@EHnS2xNeVA7pHaQV0M/ihVl9zr6OtXy4jraMk/xWl5a/2@/rduXe1cc1q9rtfInOSzXL@s3tlyeWIYv70afX04y/On1n6/O1/fLulpHWYbr@Iquosq1dQCFbS0qL2I5HuMM3Lt2JCFaMV5eWNFbP5QFyoHCjaXnZHspZimjW95uvN86Pakmt8s4ZRkHxe7monIEryu38T75gLvkoirnHwm3/bqeUVUo1QJ/BCEhgfSfkkKXdKaVbYoZ2@vjcneQ7OymulrJ14RSWbu2S0Wl1/O6jJvkh1L6KE1VPq1DrNuWAStHMtM5sxZorRZaR3WLF1OlprP0nu@6nuwn41a9qLaXi2oebOei4oVj1@OZk4KlDKaKQ@FW/S27i0IzFFCtslF1s5bQmeV0x49SpNQEQvIB21XLG9Q4GabfSFBlduN@7SIsUrm3FiFdlNsCqVAF4hwdtKcQlRfKKoLKlnbgupnw68DryCoHFTBYJxws3KkUkdnkKABTAiL8vO5yrarISJ1wdenOYHcQlEwBdFQLiYFacm2iA3Lk4kjaf9mtQhWcqI5UBMuTuDXKSUNAZJwcp4VTcK1UU9lQ2wXEK7E4pJC9lAAp3@iB9LZshvnEUS5IZ1Aaudml7EotHfMsVaMi5R6yWlwG08Q4tV3rOhUsUJQNBd3kIw5vPslLDXB2YS157@RVXLRgkkW6C/7BxTpstNnPkAUKD2QLNteRnG2N89lCnCmIE29BtKX4pRJN4VapgL3VYQAhQVM4xEd5Vo7wYXCkziv/BoSjSgGfG0wrOF@7At3hsDqf0tQtngg8FcY3mQXYNHnYPjjcqnoApV0y0gTRLnkhFESTlIVANvibO3pjGEFX2mVaWJQhiV2inUmmJB000tkS5ahCmeAKvCMMVNwxHiBKA2wDrCSYydkiSRgVO7vILKVV7JoJoJFkUj7j8QSCVlhdiD2AqpM5jZBrijG8BXBHoL5UtqPVtInwUWehVjqsRqB1nu2xrIa/8LwEhlGPSDTHtYMIYsYwSzjChkSYW4kesLKgVtJFanCPo1iGkm6HR1hYbBpwpR9CGaEQpSYQjKMTgWSRZcJ@OhuVhp5Ch5gvAZamRpAv6cQmKwwxInHTTlt88kkOET/EcF06JbGACBpGE5oIOF4ygq8KESEpUFTTcmNQhGY5ag4FYOqrXbUZGi2LDXuUl6kOcpDflMAFqygAaUKz2BL2Oy/RsfJNEZWePUBDSYDGBFIYPaMMgXAKTuEIqO0XBUiV4WPf1XQocLpim6QrIK/sAeVhgKnrUTYgADZLCJsGEbkUNN6XPYoeWSPzrNDM47/3OBCbIGZQUWFWLcR7AebkEzxuhAY4aYbaLGJOV/0LbzhWYz7SEH6QSHcFCoLsG1o4@T5R8hwoQfc2o6uVcXEizhPSLPQQi2KmIN2y2xkSLiVjRds8FrZNqlDysIb0IUN0oSiyVVuwCbDEuXWrb2xTSQDE2rCMQrKphuRZr2c3aRwiBq2WwbNGjLlj1A4oKhJZ8dSuaD8lmkjACdVI4Z6SRpQFMid6qLOJmZW@ZLUCbxuUZGR/A4LoA0yzeHMmmR7AwnZRJE0dbGX8sUKBxAo2NcpbjycU4L4ljbekDaYaskceuyHjCAFdI7@nZso9czh90xI4eoQo/bzLqGisdykK4AIhlmGUCwiEcA73KqNRpAeNWs1B25WKOk8PKJoao/Ep0Ng9EaVvEZs9bQKKioxRGwD7CkhMOmkHuXFDbNVQftKq54hJNkUYewBBtcrTFuZtKDJv0ocVgwdMUt0X/gU0UYH2OhzkhgWssU5tQHzwW5WDMAAwZxAkDQptFUMFQprWkF5PAjMYGbTjSrwQvi6aaYvCkxQmJjQCIpOqMTljzyB0Q7ntsSajMIbrw1McctziV@ViiRUgP3IzpqVQHtSu1qA4@gh3QHZ@0DtoGMAtNNbG6DIv0Z550oRCmuOnBw3tHobOMlBpDruhFqGTYwttEFnC6INsN48axj2GAIcKTdsxQ5YwNU3DjP5O/hU4h4hI4KbhQZ0dNA/mV9VuvZmWsTrKDeIrUmHg3FxkwmloihFazrSHfn2GMiKKTlc@kkwHTEB8xhhlnmc0NOMn8riNKirjcPdrOSZ/ogkwBnIF/YTPpsZyAwp270M6VXu8TBDLnbOzDIdJtSEt5Mf2fDPZEYFtoJ6OegYQwbKxi3iy24ONyhlmBWJr8pjKcBeDxpAf1QilW1biJnwPgxAgN9PR9rQPIhWZKTcAn3iB2LD@NoXQoJUPExQExI@f4Ar0uNtfkpgaYHoMYM5Ei9vQ9cw59xkV7SBTG4qGXnqfKoh525YjCGAUxEC4T9lHDJBD772sFX63pxxecWZJCNTuGf546AFzIQqiY3fFKDUVWVg9DsN6UAQ6Gf33Ys3BOFeNahpCQPAjuiHDSRX3QmEFU@aT9HATiKOZDjefdFpVu1BR7qFWmVTX5ICbaceahIp2XpYVz7T17dZxhH2j22NmdCYzhWj0NJBYOnpbcCYihH1r2l0yt5njlPvT2ie8OaM4hjDWHYAKUBczZaU2kh4mnLm1N3VplMMfL/0rA70ameLJDVNOU3FbHYf5nZ7CYgXym4aznKHKqxgJWPuM1/AxMwRjcY/lg@0ZTi2L/cFvujMzIUw80pLWqabxqaF9v9EBoJjAMrkNYyx8Xp4ph/treizeC4UVYQATRaIw6a2Zz3ukSrhpL3lVwJR8n@V4cigcBucZFAAxho59ZOwuex/ZF2QTJjnUXc44V0Ek3/dXP2LZHmFXaF/PV8ECe5W6exkEkWJtm@34QDZ4ZEt17FNpxHsMZtHB@pgNIrUNtcJqyyTC027h6eNBvBoSNc0FqjjGRe33E@5CYyZQ1pQwvvFTNUyTjupLWp3puyzLe@b23TP6ntmkq4vUM7X47UyN4JzXkGZAZt8TQg8cy3hZ5mw6PbrA6Jo64pWJ30q6uwveCyhBDXguAOvSGuljtWury2NTOkNryJi3WogCj279KiY8FcuhV9pYMCdmVtMeITY9VXhc4Fk1fDbvHhB5OSkDok0j6wu7QmFMzMp7MBhnMS5wC1vzYgqre5ze6WGI1U95TBAVe9fhnXRmCMvpZWBpv4WZuWV4LgUakrK4NBEp4Sno1JSnOjNxZYDB685ocyMTRL8/9puovfQ8E@Vdq3sXTXRoeauGsmFDOuUY04PKSSrXr3zpkNwrJFq9Pd6MnlgyAwAhu92xF@9Het4PgDy/6xfm7SLjM3rGeRHuV7dgIlNmpiEO/di7t/ngSua8fnL76FcljF7gHTc5cLeVHYx@fnl2eXg6vDo86gXx8fTb3en20@nfV8eHw83h@I6r96eHzx8@bRf@cHx/OD7o4jfHC1///vTf/bnL67n7m7Pnr/8H)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>102 98 91</s> 90 (89 + -n) bytes

```
perl -nE '$i=ord()%5,$x+=(-1..1)[$i],$y+=((0)x3,1,-1)[$i],$p{$x,$y}^=1 for/./g;say~~grep$_,values%p'
```

**Readable:**

```perl
$_ = <>; # -n
for (/./g) {
    $i = ord() % 5;
    $x += (-1 .. 1)[$i];
    $y += ((0) x 3, 1, -1)[$i];
    $p{$x, $y} ^= 1;
}

say 0 + grep $_, values %p;
```

- thanks Dada for -4 and -7

Comment: it's the first time I see "readable" and "perl" in the same post I think!

Comment: More seriously, great answer. You can still win a few byte if you use `for/./g` instead of `while`, which allows you to use `ord()` instead of `ord($&)`.

Comment: A few more things that can win a few bytes on PPCG : use `say` instead of `print` (since `-M5.010` or `-E` are free) and use `-n` flag (cost 1 byte) instead of doing `$_=<>`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>203</strike> <strike>190</strike> 189 bytes

```c
#define S(s)1-(*s%11<7)*2<<*s%11%2*16
char*t,*u;P,p,r,L,e;
f(char*s){for(P=L=0,t=s;*t;++t){P+=S(t);e=r=1;for(p=0,u=s;u<t;u++)e*=(p+=S(u))!=P;for(p=P;*++u;r^=p==P)p+=S(u);L+=e*r;}return L;}
```

O(n^2) with O(1) memory algorithm.

It loops over every position, checks if this position occurs earlier, and if not checks if this position occurs an even/odd amount of time afterwards, adding it to the total.

Answer (score 1):

## C# <s>210</s> <s>205</s> <s>139</s> <s>138</s> <s>135</s> <s>128</s> 113 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;int f(string s,int x=0,int y=0)=>s.GroupBy(c=>(x+=c%6%3-1)+s+(y-=c/3%6-2)).Sum(g=>g.Count()%2);
```

### Explanation

```
//Have X and Y as default params allows us to use a expression bodied member
//and then remove the return statement
int f(string s, int x = 0, int y = 0) =>

    //treat the string as a char array
    s.GroupBy(c =>

            //Using the unerlying int of the char this math reduces down to either x - 1, x + 1, x + 0, y - 1 or y + 1, or y + 0
            //Concat the resulting values with the original string to ensure uniqueness ie x=1 and y=11 vs x=11 and y=1 for the grouping
            (x += c % 6 % 3 - 1) + s + (y -= c / 3 % 6 - 2))

     //Mod 2 will return either 1 or 0 so we can use sum to count the groups with odd counts
     .Sum(g => g.Count() % 2);
```

- Thanks to VisualMelon for 5 bytes switching `Count` to `Sum`
- Thanks again to VisualMelon, this time for 66 bytes by suggesting some fancy math to get the translations.
- VisualMelon to the rescue again with combining the select and group by for 13 bytes and just using the input string for the x/y separator for another 2

Comment: Nice... I like this a lot. Can you not use `Distinct()` rather than `GroupBy(z=>z)`? You can also use `Sum(g=>g.Count()%2)`, since it's always 0 or 1, I should think.

Comment: I also recon you can (sadly, I rather like it...) replace the func indexing with something like `(x+=c%6%3-1)+"."+(y-=c%18/5-1)` (just add a number we compute from the char with some stupid modulus and such). I've not tested, I'll let you fix it if it's broken ;) This ought to save a lot of bytes if I've not messed up! (And there is surly a cheaper pair of expressions, but these are just what I could come up with in the last 20minutes)

Comment: @VisualMelon `Distinct()` doesn't work (unless i'm missing something) as it returns one of each string, rather than giving me a count of the occurences.

Comment: @VisualMelon good idea with using the sum, saved 5 bytes. As for your suggestion regarding the funcs, i think i need to understand why that works (it does) before i post it. is the choosing of the numbers based on the underlying values of the chars?

Comment: Yes, don't know what I was thinking about Distinct... I'm far too used to using Group as a lazy man's distinct I suppose... Aye, the stupid expression `c%6%3-1` simply maps ASCII values of `<>v^` to `-1,1,0,0` (change in `x`, note the zero values) and the other expression produces a similar result for `y`. There are probably better expressions (I didn't look very hard), a drop of ternary might pay off. This was my first effort, which perhaps makes it more obvious what is going on: `(c<61?--x:c<63?++x:x)+"."+(c>95?--y:c>93?++y:y)` (but obviously it's quite a bit longer!)

Comment: @VisualMelon thanks for the description, it does make sense now, though my math skills are nowhere near good enough to golf those expressions down without just pure brute force. :)

Comment: @VisualMelon Managed to reduce the y expression by a character, it does flip the y directions but it still produces the correct count.

Comment: This is very cool - it was even cool @VisualMelon's awesome improvements, so kudos to both of you. But (and sorry to be a wet blanket), the question asks for a program, and this isn't a complete program. I haven't been around here for a while so forgive me if I've missed some consensus on what's acceptable for C# submissions. I just feel that to be fair to each other we have to have a level playing field (among submissions of the same language of course). Not that I plan to compete with this (I was going to, but after VisuaMelon's input I can't better it).

Comment: @IgbyLargeman While i am still quite new here it has been my experience that functions and even lambdas are generally accepted unless called out specifically. I have left a comment on the question asking the OP to clarify, I will of course modify my answer if they only want complete programs.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman if you've got any suggetions for improvement, do share them! We C#ers need to put on as best a show as possible, and any opportunity we have to beat Java is a good opportunity. Yes, as much I prefer to always post complete programs, functions are generally accepted. Even none-static functions are usually accepted, so I doubt anyone is going to question the ethics of this post, especially when the Java question is just a lambda expression, it's not even named ;)

Comment: Just realised we can save 2 bytes by replace `+"."+` with `+s+` since it's non-numerical; might use a tad more memory though ;) Also,  I've not tested this, but can we not simply have the GroupBy on the `c=>...` expression, and forget the select? `s.GroupBy(c=>(x+=....`.

Comment: @VisualMelon nice catch on both of those. And also for reminding me to remove the static, noticed it last night, missed it while copying it from my test project into np++ for byte counting.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>37</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/2!.#:'=+\-99 0 99 -1 1@5!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZlNjmRFDISvMsCCBRpgkFiAjMVBkC8wC3Zx/eY5vvAbxNBdXZUv0@mfiLDr6@d/v358/PTLb9/9/MOfP/710z@f//jj06@fnh@fv3z68vfv333f3TXPj5GeF6Opqucv/z/P/7yn2b@rn3@j561dLT/4rKp99bzrtb1Pah9VSXp20y72/rPb7u/n4@ejfjb2bs@S2aefZ3f/3udmf6xN@/ox4Vm6Zq51u0sXhnr9LhBv7rrnRWtNfhY8v0vs/ezxLN/T2xfwktmXu2qfWUv2TK757LuH72rthv61C3jLd@p9tn3ZPd5/1rqifVFOk@yW50rjbfbHfvY8tiu0z/tt3GQ/rPGP3c9Ph@F52@5dI8onrsE@5Fm3f3q38j5rtvDi3oQA7PX3uTVD9rPPs3HPHvawXTT3oO2ya3ZXO3Yf78bba6fsj7F37DnfUKxfN@yemwLeeW3cAO41x3e20xM/mzYOumPX9gHHjewNbZ5gAq9I0PWgY9PxxNgB9rg3IV2c25I3241xji@6l3QSOy@cVQSVI@PAXUz4feG9ssthX/jw9q0cKVEjbbPJ0X2sbVs1ft5VPgzjkjqV6vLK4vRx7ZApjTHOUgz0lnuIL8iVhyv5/LXbhTquEJe7bdhytFtrkjQExMbZcd54r2GP4ldR23sh0gsMAAL82RppG/aBzrEchvnE0S7oZJBLwS5wkOJKb133LFXjImUNWb3POBt2cZyq1Lpv5cx2hRDcIVOpx40Wf9lLa3w@93WoP5LXcfGGTRZ5lcOfOvFl1@MGn0BWF7/AIMPmXinZJpzPEftUG@L2U8fBYEBU7ds1s42GQxIGQEjQNg7xpz1rR@QyONL3tX@NpnuY4dbJCab5Z5NLQHclrMknQ5dAeyeZMw58s1mAjchD5eI@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@NBaIDTiYOCCqw37A9Yci1hPtIQfrBITwUaguIbcWchvwcoLcQsIoQqsdqgOBHnDWkOeohNMdOQHtmdDKmUUrBCMY@NY5MrlDycI33IEF1oipRrCzYBlri3l2ahQiUFEPvACQrZpjmSZz/dadY4RAxanYDnnBiDBCkyFBWJ7Hj6VLSfE80kkIQSUlhX0oiyQua4BIA7Yhalb1ntwMcGJxnZL0AQfYBpEW/JpNADWKgUhb1F8PrwJwoFEhvYNCgfPd5QQPqWDt6SNpgayD55nIaMKxR0jfy@mhmEBH/jS5JAJ0SHTSgjZ3zplaIALhASGUa5gEAI50qvchrFejCoJS6qVCrqHDCMGi94wW1FdLwhykWAiG1dm4CiImPcBsC@BpKQTsdBadwQW3OU71ShN456a8C3lL4o1WpPR5grUBTepA@zYHG7ze1ce266KgYAbzbaOZCGBayJThUgfvjtykEYAJj0mNGg0JaLSwlxR0NmPwvMYmSgxJV4IXxTNNcW0daQ6yE0NPPMmUwzf908LnGxRZNRGMf1hUOS4xG/LpdIrAL5kZt1LYXzYF61BsXRR6QDivOL3sHDAJbQWAejJ7xEe8ZkIQrprt8ZNCg9DJ1lodIS9kAtQqfPFtogsoTRB9keHg2MZwwBDg2aVnVDlgo1XcOM/m7@DTiHiGjgRvCg7w6a@1D07hCgAoiMI9E1GpKFyFbruCiEI2iq0JE37aFfv6GMiUKdykeS@YINiN8YY8LzjIZu/EQeK6jiMq50v5Fj9ieaAGMgV9DP@BxqnDSgYPeQPM3UojIAUoq6LzpxmFUb0sJ@NK/RdoYQu6O/@zrqG0AU29Yr4snuDDamb5hViK3LYyojXQwaw350I9RpWYmb8b0CQoAcOTuJUMZddBjODcCnvkFsRX@HQmjQJpcpCgLix09wBXo87S9JTA24qQ1g3kSLZeh6QQ03o6IdZGpD0dBLv1MFM69iOYIARkEMVPqUd8QAOejtZaPwpUw5suPNkhCo0g1/MvSAuRAFpXpdcUrNRVZRj8ewGRSBTkH/t1j7MC5V45qGEBD8iG7I8FIlvVBFwUz4pDPcBOJopivNJ53WzCtUnHuoVUcV3muFfjr6LiBbSl5OFM@19UrreMJe6Pa6GV3IzCE6PQ0kjq@uCM5GhHDuXLtL5oo5zqQ/nXfC2zeKYwgT3QGoAHV1U1Zqo@lhKpk7b1PXQTn88a1/ZaA3J1MyuWHKGSpW1HGF3@kpIlYgv2s4JxnqvKqTgPPOeAMfN0MIFussP2zvSmpF7B9@052FCWHik5a0TnONzxztI5gGgGICy@S2grHw@WSmXOmv6bGKYokiLGBiSBQmvXPz@YxUCTftJV8VMCV/ZzmZHBqHwXkGBUBMoOMdGafLfkf2A9lUSA511zfOdRDJ9zTS4HouwbwVHnPeggXxKnX3bRBEiik2x/GFbMjIlup4p9KI9zrMooPNNQUiKYZGYSkyifAoLTx9PIg3R6KhuUIV17lI@X4iXWjdBCqaEsYPfrqGadJRfU2rc31XZLlubi/d6Ptmk6kuUi/Ukm9n5gRnwGPCgMy@L4QZOE7wcsLZdHp0gaW5OuIrE2U8SHdXfC/gBA3gpQCiS@ekT9RurJ6MTekMoyHrvtVCFGR0m69iKlOxPnqljQVz6mY1yghR9FSVcUFm1fDZffeAyOtLGRDtGtm88SoUxsTs/AaDcRbjgrSwc19MYbXO6eoMQ6J@JmOCmnq7jpzkO0NYSa8Ai/ItzM0tK3Mp0JCUxaWNSKlMQa@mMtW5iSsDDK9gXjaZMgnxzBOZSeidsxV9o9K7eKJDyztzlA0b0inXmV5UTlO5BajQIaVXaLS6Mt4sXSyZAYCQUjr24fsR3fcDIM//@oX7dpHxGT1jel4SJIKvmTIzDUnoz963zQdXuu/rp7SP@aqE0Qu8kyYH7o6yg9G///j4Dw)

**Explanation:**

Create list of steps, create path, group, count each repeat, if mod 2 is 0 then off, else on. Felt very AdventOfCode-ish.

```
+/2!.#:'=+\-99 0 99 -1 1@5! / the solution
                        5!  / input mod 5, "^v<>" yields 4 3 0 2
           -99 0 99 -1 1    / left, null, right, down, up
         +\                 / sum along
        =                   / group into key=>value
     #:'                    / count each value
    .                       / take the value 
  2!                        / modulo 2
+/                          / sum up
```

**Notes:**

- **-8 bytes** by stealing David Horák's method of squashing x-y into x (I know it has limitations, but it works for the examples)
- **-2 bytes** thanks to ngn

Comment: `1 -1 -99 99"^v<>"?` -> `-99 0 99 -1 1@5!`

Comment: `+/2!.#:'` -> `+/~=/'^`

Comment: First comment works for -2, second one throws an error... what are you trying to do with the `^`?

Comment: my mistake. i wanted to use it as "is null?" on the dict's values (to make them all 0s) but apparently oK doesn't work that way :(

Comment: Yeah, sadly it uses ^ as 'except' rather than null :(

Comment: except is dyadic, null is monadic. oK [does have null](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P07DwNrQ2sjawM86wTohUfP/fwA) but it's [bug](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P07Dykrz/38A)[gy](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P04pMUlBSUG/OCO/NCdFISlVwQAIDf//BwA) and [doesn't penetrate in dictionary values](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/Py4hMSFJ0UDBwO//fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 47 bytes

```
{sum bag([\+] (-i,*i...*)[.ords X%11]){*}X%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZFRa8JAEIT/yr1YEmsD9qFP2/0dgnXB0loEpZLggYi/PZ1vryFc7vZmZ2Ynl@/x9Dafb@XpUN7n@3Q9l8/9T7f9eN6V7uW4Wh6HYVj22@F3/JrKZrFe7/r78rFZvD7maX8rh246XcdL1/dz9WoRVs3Cws08wt1N5RpaVFJRJTOrlKqKrlcntRmwEMxcjSLSKj6PBhaDaCGHgEbxgdFZJFU47iGrJi1P@jTAMfRkD04QNBqwJkCkX@R1JTQ2LFC1VsaWA7YEGmbAYV8AgyJamREhT9rwVNITmMO7GixVkiK7IxVgZyxLv1xXa/OSlFIQe7Qccj5vXj0TTAVPhUzVconGmL4ZnalIkdGwl/@LlPhqB5x4@Q9sYYv/UwbmbNg1SZLAOOla/QM)

- `(-i, *i, ... *)` is the infinite repeating sequence `-i`, `1`, `i`, `-1`, ...
- `[.ords X% 11]` slices into that sequence with the ordinal values of the characters in the input string, modulo 11.
- `[\+]` performs a triangular reduction (or "scan") on those values, producing a list of the coordinates visited on the complex plane.
- `bag()` creates a `Bag` containing those coordinates, each of which has an associated multiplicity (the number of times it appeared in the list).
- `{*}` fetches all of the multiplicities from the bag.
- `X% 2` crosses those multiplicities with the number `2` using the modulus operator `%`.  Odd multiplicities result in a `1`, even multiplicities result in a `0`.
- `sum` sums those remainders.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](https://lisp-lang.org/), <strike>198 bytes</strike> 186 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(let((p 0)(c 0)(h(make-hash-table)))(progn(loop for s across i do(incf(gethash(incf p(nth(position s "^>v<")'(1e3 1 -1e3 -1)))h 0)))(maphash #'(lambda(k v)(incf c(mod v 2)))h)(write c)))
```

[Run it!](https://tio.run/##TZlNblxHDIT3OcXAWWS0MBAnW4JHIaDIciREsgRJYI7vPNZXfA7iSJqZft1s/lQVOXdPj@@vP35cv95/e719u32@/7h/uzxePmVm1PGjuo8/qisijlf6v47/ea9rXkce/6qPt2Z168FjVcxfx7tam/Nkz6Md3X3s1rNY@9dsO7@Pj4@P8thYux1Lap4@np39c56r@TE2zd@HCcfSMXOsm10yMFTrZ0Hz5qw7/sgek48Fx@9o9j72OJbP6akLaEnNn7NqnhlL5kyueew7h8/qng31axbwlu6U82zqsnO8Xsa4InVRTuuWW44rlbaZH/PZ8dis6Hleb@Mm@WGMP@w@fioMx9ty7xgROnEM1iHHunmp3UL7jNmNF@cmBGCuP8@NGS0/6zwZd@whD8tFtQ/KLrlmdpVj5/FMvD12tvxR8o48pxs268cNs@ekgHYeGyeAc83SneV0x0@mlYKu2KV8wHHV8kZPnmACf5Gg40HFJu2JkgPkcW1Cuii3u7XZbIxzdNG5pJJYeaGsIqgcaQfOYsKvC8@VVQ7zhw5P3UqRamokZTY5Oo@lbIvEz7NKh2GcUydcXVoZnF6qHTIlMUZZioHacg7RBblycSWdP3arUEsVonKXDVOOcmuUk4aAyDg5ThvPNeRR/NrU9lyI9AIDgAB9NkbKhnkgfSyHYT5xlAvSGaRSkAsUJLtSW8c@S9WoSFlDVs8zyoZZbKe2a123UmarQghukanU40SLV/LSGO/PdR3qj@RVXLRhkkVapfC7TnTZ8bjAx5CVwS8wSLA5V3K2Nc7niHkqBXHzqeIgMCCq8u2YmULDIgkNICRoCod4Kc/KEb4MjtR95V@h6RwmuFVygmn6meQS0B0Oq/NJ0NWgvZJMGQe@ySzApsnD9sV1YKoeQGmXTAjN2yUvhIJokrIQyAb/5YneGEbQlXapChVhcE1OUQ0sdvJgKRq6bpSjqhKjPAreEQYq7hgPEKUBtgFWEqyhxaQehVFxsovMUlqRT@UrgL6QDh5PIGjC6kLsBVTdzGmk/G7FGN4CuENM7LItak1xkhna3LXSShaVttZDGmtZLX/h@QjKWdsqEs117SCCmLHMEo6wIRHmVqIHrCyozXDxxRlHsQwl3Q6PsLA4NOBKP5RQZlEsrUsvi@iGqbf1gQpPd6PSgrBonfkSYGlqBPmSTmyywhAjEjftCJllW5D5AT/Ecl06JbGACBpGE5oIOF4ygo8KESEpUFTTuDEoQrMcNYcCMPXVqdoMjcBSG/YoL1Md5CC/KYELVlEA0oRmsSXsd14KqCHGIiq9Z4CGkgCNCaQwekYZAuEUnMIVVPbxUwFSZfjYq5SE8j9UUqStohGIuQblYYCt61U2IAA2h2IESiNyKWi8L3sUPbJG5lmhmcf/73EgNkHMoKLCrCrvO49VEZXmcSM0wKnEQUEZ1hP2Byy5VmM@0hB@kEh3BQqC7Jvmzo38LqA0ELOIEKpEaoPiRJwnpFnoITbFTEG6ZbczJFxKxoq2eWxsm1Sh5GEt6UOG6EJRZKu2YBNgiXtrqRe2qSQAYh1YRiHZVEvy7Nd7mjQOEYNWy@BZK8YgQYoMRUUiK546Fe2nRBMJOKEaKdxb0oiyQOaoBIA7YmalL1mtwNsGJRnZ34Ag@gDTLN6cSaYHsLBdFPIWwcvFHysUSKxgU6O89XhCAe5b0nhL2mCqIXvlsRsyrhDQNfJ7a6YQErzGlyRBrxAtNqGMlPHRpxQFcIEQyzDKBQRCOId7ldUo0oNGreai7UpFnQOGVuMBL6itsI4XRKkIELHZ2yagqMgYtQGwr4DEpJN2kBs3xFYt5StV6I2t3hLwjXZf5GqVpy3M21Bk3qQPk2BRu83tVHtqusIGAG8yWjnghgWssU5tQHzxW5WDMAAw6TGtQaEtFVc7xGkN6f0kMIORQTuuxAvh66LZtoi2hlw3oaGZq9Zkmvnt5nGJis2ajMJYrg8c4hy3@FW5WGIFyI/cjG0plAd1qjUojj7CHZCdH/QOGgawhMbaGF3mJdozJgtWSHv99KCh3cPQWQYqzWE31CJ0cm2hDSJLGH2Q7eZRw7jHEOBQoWk7dsgSpqZtmNHfyb8C5xARCdw0PKi7g@Y6FL1bBCgAIuGIdU0XyUJkI3u5yITT0FSgI3faQ7@@QxkRRacrH0mmCyYgvmOMMs8zGtrxE3ncRhWVcbj7tRyTP9EEGAO5gn7CZ1NjuQEFu4vkSaYW4QFQu6hzo2OHSbUhLeRH8Rptpwkx0/o7t6PeAUSwbZwinuz2YKNyh1mB2No8pjLcxaAx5Ec1QumWlbgJ38MgBMiRs@UIedxFh6HcAHziJ8SG9bcphAatfJmgICB@/ARXoMfd/pLE1ICaWgPmTrRYhq5vqGFnVLSDTG0oGnrpc6og5m1bjiCAURAD4T7lHDFADn32slb43Z5yeMedJSFQu3f446EHzIUoiI7TFavUVGRh9bgM60ER6GT0P4s1F@NcNappCAHBj@iGDDdV3AuFFUyZT9LDTSCOZjrcfNJpVZ1CRbmHWlVU4b1s009a3xlko52XZcWzbX27dVxh3@j22BmdyUwhWj0NJJau3haciQjh3Np2l8xt5jjl/rTOCW/uKI4hjHUHoALUxU5ZqY2khwlnbp1NXRrl8MfP/pWBXq1M8eSGKaepuK2Ow/xOT2GxAvltw1nOUOVVrASsc8Zr@NgZgrG41/LF9gynlsX@4jfdmZkQJl5pSetU2/jU0j6CqQAoJrBMbsMYC5@XZ8rh/poeKygWK8IAJopEYdJbO5/3SJVw017yVQFT8nOW48mhcBicZ1AAxBg6zpGxu@xzZF@QTZjkUHe541wFkXx3Iw2u@xLMW@Ex5S1YYK9Sdz8HQaRY22Y7PpANHtlSHedUGvEei1l0sL5mg0htQ62w2jKJ8LRbePp4EK@WRE1zgSqOdVH7@wl3obETKGtKGN/4qRqmSUf1Ja3O9l2W5b1z@@4dfe9s0tVF6pla/O1MreA0eJQZkNn3htADxzJeljmbTo8uMLq2jvjKpD0epLsLvhdQghrwXADWpbXSx2rXVpfHpnSG1pCx32ohCjy69Vcx4alYLr3SxoI5sbOa9gix6anC4wLPquGz/e4BkZebMiDaNrJ@41QojInZ@QwG4yzGBW5ha7@Ywupep3d6GGL1Ux4TRMXZdfgk3RnCcnoZWNrfwuzcMjyXAg1JWVyaiJTwFHRrylOdnbgywNAK5mXlKVMjnnnCM4k@52xB39juXTTRoeWtWsqGDemUY00PKiep3ABU6JDcKyRavT3ejN5YMgMAIbvdsRffj/R@PwDy/K9f2G8XGZ/RM7rnJUEs@JIpM9MQh37tPdt8cCVzv35y@@ivShi9wDtucuBuKzsY/dPNL79cn@4/rtfXy@8317v58XB9vv3n/vPD7fvD54/bv57ub25urq9vL39/vz69vLxevr28Xd4vt3dvL@/vl8fL15fr4/e7b9e/7z/mEb24vF6/fzxcX1/eHz8eX74fyz9N3X26@e365f7Py5fL5/n1@cux88Nx5LH/8@3rPH359bfr0@3zX19vr/9c@obN7q7PL18vffljlt9c/317/Li/3B0vfvz4Dw)

**Explanation:**

```
(let ((p 0)(c 0)(h (make-hash-table)))
  (progn
    (loop for s across i
      do(incf (gethash (incf p (nth (position s "^>v<")'(1e3 1 -1e3 -1))) h 0)))
    (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (incf c (mod v 2))) h)
    (write c)))
```

- **p** is a hashtable map key, generated as an index of the character within the string "^>v<", remapped to values 1000, -1000, 1 -1 representing the x,y. (x axis is +-1, y axis is +-1000)
- the hash value at that index is incremented by 1 (switch counter)
- the hashtable is than looped trough, and the map function increment the final count as modulo 2 of the value on a given key

Note: i (input) is defined it test as:

```
(defparameter i ">>><^>>>^vv><^^v^<<<>>^<>>^<^>^<<^^v^<v^>>^<<><<>^v<^^^vv>v><^>>^<^<v><^v<^<<^^v><>>^v<^>^v<vvv<<<v^vv>>^vv>^^<>>vv>^<^>vv<>v^<^v<^^<v^^^<<^><><>^v>vvv<^vvv<vv><vv<^^v^^<^^>>><<<>^<>>><^<<<>><>^v><^^vv<>>><^^^<^>>>>v<v^><<>v<v<v^<<^><v^^><>v>^<>^^^vvv<v^>^^^^v>v<v>>>v^^<v<vv>><<>^vv><<vv<<>^^v>>v<^^v>><v<v<<>^^vv>>^v>v>v<>^>^v<>>><>v>v<<v<^<>>>vv>>v>^<>vv^v><><^v^>v<^^>v<^v>>v^>^>>v>v>^>^<^^>vv>>^vv<^><>^><<v^<><<^<^>^^vv^<<^^<^^v<v<>^>v>>>>>>vv<<v>^>vv^>^><^<^^><<vvvv>vvv<><<><v^vv><v^^<>^>><^vv<><>^>vv>>>vv^vv<<^v^^<<v^^>^>vvv<><<v>^>^>v<v>^<^^^^<^>^>><>>^^vv<>v<^>v><v<v^>>v<^v<vv>v^>v<v^<^^^^v<^<^<<v<<<v<v^^>vv^>><<<v>>^^^>^<^>>>v^v><^^vv^>><^^vv<vv<v^><>>^><<<>>^^v^v<<v^<vv^^^>><>>^v^^^>>^>^<<^>v>^^v>><>v>^>vv^^<vvvv<><^v>^><<>>><^<^v^<<vvv^v<<<<<><><<><><<v>v<v>v><^v^^vvv>><>^>^>^v<<vv^^^v^vv><v><><v<v<<>>>v<^<^v<<>^v<<^v<><>v>>^^>^<v^<<^v^^^vv>><v^<v>^v><^<>>>>^^<vv<>^^>^>v^v^^>><>^^<^v^<v<<v<^<<^^vv>v>^<vv<<^^v^vv^>^^<>v>^>^<>vv><v>>><<><<vv^^<vv<>>^v>^<<vv>^><<>^<v>v><<v^<v<><v>^<^<^><^^^^>>>^<>^^><>>v^<vv^<^<<vvvv>>>v^v>>^>v^><<>>v<>>^>><vvvvv<<vvvv<v>^v<vv^<>><<><v^^<^<v>^v<^<<>^v<v^<>v<<>^<<vvv><^><^^^<>>v^<<>vv><^^^>><^>v^v>v<v^>>v>>v>vv<<v<<vvv^^^>^<v^^<^<v<^<>>v^<<v>>v^><v<vvvvv^^^<v^^<><v<<^>>^><^<v^v^^>><v><>v>^<vvvv><<v^^v^>^>v>><>^^v>v^>vv^>v<^<<^vv^>vv^<v>^<v^<>^v>v^>v^<<>^^<^>^^>vv^>>vv>v>vvv><>^v<<<<v^>v^^v<><v<v>^<^><^><<v<>><<>v^^>>><<><>>><<>><v^^>><^>><^<>v^^vvv>v<^<<vv^>vv^><<>v><>^<>v^^v>^>v^<>^><v>^><<^v<v^^<v>><^^>>^<^<^v<v>^>^<^<v><><>>>><>^<^<v>v<v^>v><>v^>v^<<><^<>>v<^vv^^^>^<<<<>^>^<><^vvv>^^<v^v>v>v^v>v>>vv>^><>^vv>^<v<v^<>vv^<v<><>^>>vvv><>>^<<v^<<>^<v^>v<^^^<^<^^<>^>>v>^<v>vv<v^^>><<<<<>>v>^v>^>>>>v>>^^>^<<<^<<<v>>^><<<<^vv<<>^v<^>v^<v<<>v<>^<^<^<^<>>^^^vvv<v>^vv>^><^<v^>^v<v>><><vvv<^^>>v<^v>^>>>><v^<v^^<^^v<vvv<v>^^<<>><^<v^v<^vv>v>vv>^^<>^^^^>>^v><vv<<<v>^v^>>v^>><<<^v^v<<>><<vvvvv<v^vv>vvvv><v^v<^^^><vv^^<>><>><^>^^^^v>v><><v^<>^v<>^^<^^>^^^vvv>>vv^v^<v<vv^v>v>>>^v^^vv^<^v>v^v>>^v>v<v^<^^><vvv>><<>><>><v>v<^<v>>>>v^^v^^>^><<v><^<<>>v<>^^<<>vv^>>vv^^^v>>>^v^><v<<^>v<v><>>>^>>^<<>>^><<vv<^^>^^^v^^<>>>vv><<>v<><<<>v<<>>>v<>v<>^<vv^v<^^<<<v>^v>>^^>^><<^vv<><><>v>^v>^<>v>>^^^<^^>>vv>v<<<v^><<v><^v><>v<^<<^<>^vv>^><^^^^^<<v^^<>v>><^<v^^^vv>^v<>^<v<v>v>^><^<<^<>><^^>vv^<>^<>vv<>>v<vv^>><^^<^>v<><>vv<v<>>v><v^^^>^^^<<vv^><^^v>v>^<^>v^><<vvv>v^><vv<><^<><^>^v<><<v^<<><>^^^^<<^>>^>^v^>v>^<<^>vv^vv^v<>^<<^>v<^^<<v<v<<<^>vv^>><>v>><><v>v><v^><vvv>vv<<vvv>v^<<^v<^<><<^v>v<>>vv<<v^>v>v<<>>^vv^<^^^<^v>>^<vv>^<v>><>v>^^<<v^<>>>>>v^v>><>v^>>^<>>^<^vvv^^^<^v<><vvv^>^>v><<v>>^v>v<v>v^<v>v>^<>vvv>vvv^^<>vv>^^^^^>v<<^v<>>>><<<>>><vv>>^v^^v<v^>>>^>^v<^v>^v<>vv<><vvv^v<<<<v<vv>vv^<^vvv<^v>v^^vv<^>>>^^>>^^><>^>>v<>>>^^<<v<^<<<<<^^<v^^^<<>><<<^>^v^>vv<>>>^^v><<>^^^^<vvv><^^<>>>^><<^>><v>^<>^v^<vvvv^>>^><<>><^<v^>>vv^vv<^>>>><^>^v<^<v<^^<^<^><^<>>^<>v^v<<>v>v<>><<v<^v<<<^v<v<>><v<^<^>>v>v>><v^<v><>>>>>v^v>><^<^<v>><v^v>v<>v<v><<<>^^><>^^<^vv^^<>v><><><^>^^v^vv^<><>>>>v><>>^>^<<^<v<v^>v^^<v>>><<^^vv^^>><<^<vvvvv>><^>^>>^vv<><<>v>v^<<<^v<^^<<^vv>v<vvv><^v>vv^vvvv<^>^v^<<<<^v<<<>^vvv>^v><<>>v<v<^v^<>v>>^^v^vv>>>^v^^>>^<><><<<<^vv>>>>>v>v^>v<>><<<>^vv>^^^^<^^^>^^^^>^^^v^v><^>^>>>v<v<^<^^<<^v<<^<>vvv^^^^v^<<>vv>^^>>><^^v<^<<<v<>v<<><>v<><>^<v<<^>^^>><<v>^^><^^v<^<v^<^^<>^<>^v^>>^^v^v^<>v<>^<<<>^v^v>^<vvvv<>v<<>vv^<<>vv>>>>^<v><>>>v^><<>^v>><<>>^^v><^<>>vv^^^>vv^<^^v><v>>vvv^v<^v>v<<^^<>v^^^v^^>><v^>>v^v^vv<^>v^<^>^>v<v^><vvv^>^<>v<<^><^^<vv>v>>vv>v^>>^vvv>>v^>^^>vvv>>v><<>>^^v>v<v<><<<<^^v<^<>^v>><v^^^<>>vvv>v><<v>^^<^vvvv^v>v>^vv>^vv^^v><<>>^^>>v>>>^v><^>v<^^<>vv>v>v^^^>>^^^><<<<>>^>>^<^v<^<^<>^><v<<v>v<>^>>^<<v^^<v^vvvvv>>v^>>^^^<^^<><<><><>^v>vvv^>^^>v<^^>^<<^v^^^><>><<v<^^^<<<<>><>><<^^v><v^<<^v<v><<>^<v>^>^v>vv>><v^<^<v<v<v><^^^^>>><^<><^v^v<<<^>vv^<v^>^^v^>>><<<<^<>>><v>>>vv^>^^<v^v>>>v^<^<>vv>^v^^><<<v>v>v>><>>>v<^>^<>>^^<v^<<^<v^>><^v^><><v><><v^vvv<<>v>>><<><v>v<>>><^<^^v<v>^<<>^v>^>^>^^<^^><^>>>>><^^>vv>^<^^<><^>^<^^><^<v>v^>><^>^^^>>v^v<^>>^<v^<>^><><v>>^v<v^^^^v<^vv><^v>>^^^<>^<^<^>vv^v<<>vv>^<>v>^>^>vv^v<vv<^^^v<v>v>v^<^^^v><v<<<^^<><^^>>>><<^^v<<^>v<<vv^^^vv^vv^<v><>^v<v>>><vv^v<v^>>>>^<<<vv^>>v>^><<><<^<^><<vv^>v^>><>v^<<<>v^><>><<>>v><>v^<v><>^v>>><><>>>^vvv^v>vv>>>^^v^><<v<>>^^^v^^><<^v<><><v<<v<v<><<<v^<^^^<>v^^v<^^<<^>v<<v><^<<<<>><>^v>^<>^<^^v^vvv>^^<>^>><v^^vv^<>^<><<^^^v<^^^>>^^v>^>^<^>v><<^<>^v<><vv^vv<><<<<<<v<<v<<vv^<<^<^vvvv><v^v^v<>>>vvvvv^<vv^<^<>vv>^<><<v><>v^^<v<>>>vvv^><^<^>v^^<v>^<>>>^^v^<vv<<<<^><v<<<>v<<<v<>>^^^>^><>v>^v^>^<v^^><^v^^<^v^^>^v>>^^^<<><><<<>v>><^><>>>vvvv>v>>v>^^^^v<><vv<^<v^v>>^^vv<^>vvv>^v>>><v<v<v^<^>^^<vvv<vv<v>>^vv>^<<^<^<v>v^<vv^^^v>vv<v><v><v>^<v>>vv<>v>^^>v^^^<>v<>v^v<>^<><v><^>^<v^v><<^v^v^v<<v><<^^<^vv>^<^v><>v>><v^v^>><><><<<v<>v<^vv>v<v<<>^vvvvv^<<<^<vv><<><>v^<^v<<<^>v>v<v^<<^>v<<^<v><<<^>vv>v>^<^^v>>>><>vv>>vv>vvv<>^^<>^v^<>vvv<^^^vv>v><<<<vv^v><v^<^<<<><v<>^><<>^>v<^^<<>v>>v<<>><^^<<<^<^vv^^>v>v<>^^>>^v^vvv>^v^>v>>v>v>v>>vv^<><<<<>v^^>vv<^^v>>v<vv<^>>^<>^^v<><vv^<><v><v<<v^v<^^<^v^v<>v<<><vvv><<<^<^^<<>>^v>>>^v>>>v<>>^><<<><><<<v<vv<^<>v^^v^^>^<<^^^v^>^<<^>^>^>>>>v<v<v<>vv<<vv^<<^<vv>^^<^<<>><^v><><>^<v><v^>^v>^<^>^^><v><<^<v^^<<^><><v>v<>>><<^><v<^vvv^<<<>><<>^v^^><vv>vv<>^>^>vv<>v^<^<>vv><<>^<v<vv<^<^<><^vv<<^>>>v<>><<>>>^^^^<<^v>>v<vv>^^>v<v<vv^><<><>>>v>>^^v<^v^^>>v^<>>v^>><^<^^v<v<><<><>>^<>><^v<^^^^><>^>vv>>^vv<<>v<<<<<<><<<><<>><v><^^^<>>v<^><^vvv<>^>^^v>^<v><^v^vv^<<>v<<<<v>^vv>>v>vv<<^>^<>>vvv^<v<><>><>^^^^vvvvvvv<<>v<^><^^>vv^^<v<<^^<vvv<v<v<<>><<><v^^>><^<>^v^vv<<v<v<>><<>>>>>^vv<><v<>v><v>v>><v<v^vvvvv<><>v>>v<><<<^^<>^<^^<v>v^<vv>^vv^<>^<<^<vv><v<v>>v>^<>v^<<v^<v>^v<>><v>>>>^<<^^^v<^<>><^<><v>>vv^>^<^<^>>v^>^^^^>vvvvv>^v<^><^^<^^>^<^^^^^^^>v>>vv>v^^^v^^^<>v><^>>>v>^>^>^>vv<vv<^^>>^>>>v<>v><<^<<v^>^>>>>^^><^^<v<<<<>>v>v^v^^<>><v<^<<<<v^^^^<v<<<^>v>^^<vv<^^^^^v>^v^<v><>>^^>^v>^>^vv^v>v>v^>v>^>>^^^^>>^>>^><>><v>v>>><<^v^v^>^>^>>vv><<^>v<v<v^<<>>^v<<^v<<^><^>>^<v>^>vv>v>^^^>v^^<^<^^>vv>^^><v>>^v>^v<<^^^<<^v^>^<<^>vv^>>^<^v><<>v><^^^<^^>>vv>^vv>><^<<<^>vv^v>v<^<<<^<^<<><^^>>>v^<^^^>^<><^v>>^<<v<^v>>v^<^<^<^^^<v^><<vvv^<^v^vv^vv<v<<v<^<>^v>^^^<^^v<v<v><<<^<>^^^^v>v^v^v^v<v><v>>^v><vv^^^v>><<v^vvvv<<<^v<<><^>^<v^^v<>vvvv^vv<>^v<><>^^<>>vvv<^>><v^<<>v>v<>^v^>v^>><<>>^^<^v<>>^>^><>>^<v<v^^<^v><v^<v<><><^<<><v^v<<>vv<v<v<^>>><>vv^^<><<v<^^<<^<><^^^>^>>>^<^>>>^>><^^^<^v^^^v^v^v>v>v><vv>><vvv<<v><><^^>^v<v>><v><^><^<<>v^vv^v><^vv>^>>v<vv><^<^^v<^^vv<vv<v<v>v><v<vv<<>^^v^^v<<<^<>v^^^<><>>><^>v^^^v^vv<<<^>>v><^>v^<>>>>^<>^^vvv^^<><^>^^<><>^vvv^^<vv^>vv^^^^v<>vv<^^^v<<>><<vvvvv>v>^^^vv>><v><v<>vvvv<v^><^<>^>^<>v>v>v^vvvv<><^v>>>^^>><vvv<>^>^v^<vvv>v^vv^vv><>><>v^^v^vv<^v>vv>>v<v><^<<^v<>>^vv^<v>v><v>v>^v>^<v>^<<^>vv>v<^<^vv^<^><<<v<<^^vv<vvv><>v>v<vv^<><><^vvv>>vv<^^^v><^v><<^>^^v>^<>><v<>>^^<<<v><>^>^><vvvv<>^<<<><<<^<>>v^vv^>><^vv^^>^<v^<v>><^^>>>^v>^v<>^v<><^><vv>v^^^<^>>^<<^<^><<<^^<v<<^vv<^<>v<^<<^^<v<vv<<><v<v^<>^<>v>>v<^v>v<>^^vvv<>vv^v^<><v^vv^<^v^v><>^><v^<>>^^^<>>vv^<v>^^v><v<^>^^^^^^><>>vvv<<><><v<^>v<>v^v<<<<>v^>>>>^v>^^<v^>v><v^<^^v<<<<v<<<>^v<^>^v>v^^>v^^vvv>vv<>^>v><v<>^<vv><>>><<^>>><<v>v^^<^<<<<v^<>>>v<<<^v^vv<>^v>v<<<<>^^>><v><>v<v><^^>><>^>^>v>>><v>^vvvv<><><^>>^v^><<>^v<><><^><<<>v^^>v>^>v^<v^vv<>><^vv^^>^^><vv<<>v>v^^>><v^>^<^<>>>vv<>^>v>v^<>v<^<<v>>>^<>v^>v>>vv^^<>>v<v<<^<>v>v^<^^^>v^^>v>v>vv<^<v>v^^><<<v<><>^^<>v>v>^^v>v>v^v>>^<v^v>><>^^>^<>>>^vv^><v^<^>v^>^v><^>^^^vv^^v<>vv<>>^><<^v>^v^>>v>^v^<<^^^vv<<vvv>^vv^v<<<v^^<<><vv<>>^^vv>^^^vv>><><v>v<^v^>>>vv^><>><v<^v<>^><v<^^^^>><^<>v>^v<^vv>v>v<^<>v>v>^<vv>v<^>vvv<v^<vv<vv<>v>^><v^v<>>>>>v>><^v<>v>^v><v^v^vv<>^<vvv^>><v^<vvv^^<^vvv^v^<>><v>v^^v<><>v^^^v<<<^><v<<<>><<vv<<><vvv^v>>v^v<v^>>><<v<>^v><>vv<<v>v^vv>v^v<^<vv<><><^v>^<vv>v^^>>^^^><vv<><^>>>^<v^<<^^>^>vv^><v<vvv>^^>>>^><<vv>vv>^<>>^^><^v><<>^<<<v^>^")
```

Comment: Does this mean that going up 1 is the equivalent of going right 1000 times - and you could clash? I like the idea of compressing x/y into a single dimension though so I'm going to nab it :) PS - you can use `(99 1 -99 -1)` to shave 2 bytes..

Comment: @streetster correct, that's the idea. To compress the x/y into 1d, where y must have some buffer to not interfere with the x. (and yes it might actually clash - therefore bigger gab, smaller the chance - thus I am using actually 1000 (1e3), so 999 would be the same byte length).

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
+/≠/×⊢⌸+\0j1*'^<v'⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZrNinbVEYXnfRXOGqLBOC/qSqRACEpEUPigIDcQTUhCJsGpeAuZOM@d9I182bWeVeecjoi@/fY5e@/6W2tV7f7qh@9@/8c/f/Xd9998fPvnv//0/dtf/vXFy9tPP3798dPP3/76y@f//fntb7@@/f23T7/8w7df/O61ol/f/vGf8@jH89DHD5@c5187O@r8JqKiMiKrMjPO113nP@er8@X5KiJ6vurzZZ5/z0/ntZjH6jwWeV48C53/nvWyePiscJaN15cPn2mv8/xscRY4686z5@ezWJ/n57lZtOPsmdpGB5kf6/yjd@ZEs3HMC3PE80Dp3HOM86tjofeqOVbUnCL49Rwz56XQCzGHi9bKs2jMUsXXY/JsouUrteP5p@aQY8N54bnXeXuW0iqlnWaXMTN0/vl1z8dx7zgmxjOFf2Rv6uz6kKGdUjvJ22NpXnsVK8uOcclYOV4eU@e4iud4b/5/Ps3j4/aJ03ycVcs/yZE5H@YTW5@D3D6c89Skx@vL1y8fXl7ImXlqzlpj2JghpygHFHu@G3MU1FlavpUxhR/nUwfPzr6kTSsDxidXzjT7KFeUKYVzS@/LklJEUya0YqBYpOIxAQmSOjBXOYnZnP/OzyTisi4VkXGXYkPW4EQ5rsrZSnqej/OOakmJGfgnCBRpVrdd8rR/JRsnNxVRjqEfJ02DEmFXVeWkahNo5fhsm4pVz/v6epa8fSj/lJJNya3iaxk1j89BJpMy05k1C7VWDa2n6se7qUKVbX1VydOHWooULVWbkGJcV7tAO3MVTxw@y2RuwpbyHiwIpYWqd85/@1DlOsGkuJpSpepmKflCQSHOTUFTqII2@YRtq@UdkIKMnE@7V5LYqocmPNpNSCfwaC1GeqkmBIGhOsZpMryDMmjlj7KQoN94MhvbwfMSaSJHjCtUToIBkFRoW7hZqSQzyG1gqwRv@H@emk1vH@qwTrVwleqN4BTgNJkFlKmWlBJeejaTwbigMFHnmPPfPoRkSi6miMbTuD3KSUbAdFg5VBukyEGpqbIDKwpCUSJi9I2TOGoekc/0Ynp7NsUc4i3XpDMuzRPsVnaxtoh99zx0x0tBap6lKsSo8Fys09vYISvhnqLsAIgmfwlE85NK5Pzv9iHPyTzqmKRX3LRwknV6CvajzmR8tDnYkAjmL0EInm/812Oqe4LDVmJwQanYE/ofFyj68vkcW2REyDsMTCR0Ct/48cYNsXNcxuFo@UH@D@hOlQYfNJhZKBLtDlWEw@78SwuK24fKhiJTwVEdEzBr8rftEBhf9QQruOSkWKINIVHtytTxbw4V@2r1QCTVpm9vcihNMy1/ypDHbtHOPFOjDI90VgXV@uDKgplKJRlw6SCZKCJ1zrIMo5yEMySkJYOlnTAwLnbT8eqBGx2X4gPIJPhUB0QkgbgJvwu6F8BlqdMOsalcgD8hioin5jEMrOLUZsJh2UatdVg7ITtYo/eEtTwqQhfqL6pq5YeWQ1fgOIKdxDeB3IKJFUzCJapGLQjaJbSkaa84i@WAhhsPCaMwV/4MyEF5oXSJVZ9K50Cp1qpeKEDknbCxbKVSUYF3vMJ4amltxRuJ7EoXBNlj6JLIMO21pTQ/yUHipVjOfeylXOFERNqwndBUoEEkd/hVIXak9IpqHPcGxWy2pWZRKPX0YaI0hTWGYIt@wytlauqFnORPJX7BagpQmlgtFsU5Tx2lKhR1JZ2CxPjuBepKqjRHIfVL@kuZBOEVnIZJ9BSXkr1xQ9VKDPx005@hOZQDSZpDLso22AXmWZxYJQaicPbZ@JEb9BAJqHegPoUSkhyBRFTbFFaa1hlXRBA@wS@aumpEdz2wt2hVChIh/9AZZgbaAVrCNotZcwhPhGOY2ZijvAl4qR/9pjsEUNI@o7FVbJLOBQMTVmkrDjVyLnJBJHBGZ7aAP6e97LJAdZvhjAqXpDGofVw28NlU6eRtrSiBnNG3ouwJye1DWA3Ywx96xS@0qSwAfm1c5iGdrVaEsG7vrtJkRPTuo2lkAOtaUel@WjuhCCkAxV27o2GVmCIfJ2Aj9XuhQYz@mA/IiOil9Ca27nDUPihBfBYlJdXTgC06hiNahDrjTEs3f4mDXVRJqwtrGt@sqCDTguXNLu47Eupx35bGd9Kr3/nQVLFtgBtVTArkBO3G1lx50hBO@7TEj16BzTTEZViPGYuescQG4IEmy0nKDYSjQQj3aquppG@Nio3h7YqnC3noeboLapVGsEB/94hAiUV69rZHKEIyS@0PqkAAZdJLHHbXcvqZIC2QJsmgIxHJ6c0R/h7nUPWKgBuQNsSZx@lL69ZszbgCq1XDHuAoggWMygjlCj0jDBnW3w15LF@o8hAuAPMDo1DlwjnIjBENoU9rYq8r4RyMXtrxJ54Iexfdtofxf3Mq5lE0QCKzqjUh48o49E25/bOmpLBWi4RnZdSGxb3K7dE77OStXaT0U7I1wjWpLIFy6Z/cCTo4Qc@koQqPMJDgq3d5mAydRMLUJdMuuyU9uGn3cnTggdp0ehjaE1rZM9EOPuaKtitcLeZ304fHOuBcodk7dogVpsgdNNBnJP8WOPrAQ@ED0YKX5RNYJJgeVnt0wcySXVCgEHGRMksj5kITXt8YFZAqCMV0jXnHDr9EVJ1GkqRAm16uDdfMGdAhjOJ27Bfv5htt1BIshKcGlpXyN9qFQ0H6oKz4wFRdbtThimtkKvR4zDB3vlueODgrcaTUZ@O5Wp6lPTdBZ7rPyJ1E7EAnWPYRLzcvVIcHRpU7TAzE4uY/leVuDi0k/6ohTLf2xFW8wozzzg3AdGfZ7SksBC9yVS4BbnFDerjPMIXRuJaNCwoJYfLQNhwWI5gAxLbCjLyTOwCAeSeKPEYfwzT6mg3SLjMdky/v3oGOcKc0UgRtSxAuMBqiJdynXSMbCYrsq/d3R9Pt6dE7/nJ7hZJyscbeUuxABMUEkq6LVnFqFh9Ww8v8Hsz1O7vMPlfx52Kpq04YASHR6NBcQM6bUu4Jw4qrzGfpIfQdr6ZCLKcYhJZbHAsr5SoqnHuH2lzxEMI5QQJGO4/LCu3iFI9H2i32NjRNnxI7M2VVQV5t3wD0llzRFtCJWGJ/SLAfGjsX8qgr5XNdE/rc0SjDLuskwAoojZ2OU1tJDxfO@HrMAbaxBU3x093vM2itlVWekDGNtkRoq/@w/qCXsrjS7@6ZgxvzcmYrD2MlbV0zesPSzmSM/b2WLKeomSfdGRhHPeYADAURxG2W3uuVppWsbQBrZYnv9wBAJudM3MNYjt7gEu8xI/J8gt6T28Kwwg3gp0gsJvW19y8egZMWtOFcDXH7cc3M@lHLbI8DEyYE@heSrtG/pxPX1UxBdmGyRaXmjuEV5HzMD33huXxio5iT@4avdlpa9jb1ew/eSEnsAkd8m0RfUY/5IdV13TLQrMRiIh2/zW4Qr31wK8S2vCN87REIc5CBnIfeWHI37QbqP9Z17Xspd@uxkz9rZBSJcVpYwJAD9ap26dbY24@6Dem9n@neK42dIbtKSVVTm2/pau@t9xIbRmb69sh5Qu3BcBmfy5qCTpguObq2Drky8922u97g/kcJbUClcG7cQHfXSjareVtRHnPTOVsTx95@Il48cveVXDAY9OWsquTeq41psbOx9oi36THD4xffPcCre@eEWM1NLRCz3fD7i3jYhQpjvq0drmAxTmT84pa/9uISK3qD0ukhk1VbedzyTkctdlr3JWI7txldwGrfxu18GT3OTZebJAIoEPP0hRnSoyfqVXW1k3IGQ1yeR5urmfD6rxR8U3mVsGfY3OC7d9Pk7F3OuysPus6d3pOwvhhKtxJcRQZ/RlDM5tPXD/4TgNrmyQmi6nnoeWCIRrE8Zi9fG5YRz33S3lIzxqSn3j@/8B8GgL3cFjBl6njOe2vPf41LwKvMvZ50m@2rMkZc8J6bPbSFFSqKQ3928D8)

uses `⎕io←1`

`⎕` input

`'^<v'⍳` find the index of each input char among `'^<v'`, i.e. `^` becomes 1, `<` 2, `v` 3, and anything else 4

`0j1*` *i* to the power (the imaginary constant)

`+\` partials sums

`⊢⌸` matrix in which each row is the list of occurrences (indices) of a unique partial sum; padded with 0s to make it rectangular

`×` signum - all indices become 1s, the padding remains 0s

`≠/` sum mod 2 for each row

`+/` sum

Answer (score 0):

## [krrp](https://github.com/jfrech/krrp), 137 bytes

```
^>:\L\T[length],^v>xy:!tTxy!V?[elem]tv[without]vLtELtv?#?E>V!c#!f>?=c$62.@V#!r>+x1y?=c$60.@V#!r>-x1y?=c$94.@V#!r>x-y1@V#!r>x+y1.LT00E>00.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LDoIwEPyWBk4gTdsYoyQWL731SLjwuBAUIz5Cam2/viI2UtTLZHZmd2ZPfX8zBQeBqWhc8CLNu@ZyEG25qCRVOgYiVRpkSd50zbkUMn8cRXu9i1JywbiQiZcwmoHaA3uabGt/ReAu80BPQ4X1KCArRFbYLK2gIo0tCzWGPEWIUYSgCbiP8RryV9iHogGGUwvj6DiT7TAyc8fRSSBzcAKn1jeO@z/edwf584sbz8wT)

---

## Explanation

```
^>:\L\T                ~ lambda expression, import list and tuple module
 [length],^v>xy:       ~  the answer is the number of lattice points
                       ~  which were visited an odd number of times
  !tTxy                ~   current lattice point 
  !V ?[elem]tv         ~   if the lattice point is already present,
      [without]vLtE    ~    remove it, else
      Ltv              ~    add it
  ?#?E> V              ~   no further moves
  !c#!f>               ~   move character
  ?=c$62. @V#!r>+x1y   ~   move right
   ?=c$60. @V#!r>-x1y  ~    move left
    ?=c$94. @V#!r>x-y1 ~     move up
     @V#!r>x+y1        ~      move down	
 .LT00E>00.            ~ initialize at point (0, 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJBb6MwEIXPm18xUXrYtjQiUVXtVlrSS24co1ySVHJhKKM1NjIDgR72r2eNISm04TDyaD6/N8/irzH5aR9O706vwfM@3G/gy/cPpMjeYgFY5waLgrTygLJcGwZJBYNQMXCZS4RMx6XECewkqndOD95rFdTN80UIOEWLF0c0QIXrVJm92U4n1oWZIoRck@JiAtc/K3JMKUrBaiBUVBBjbDVBx/FAjCnDVmPKm7q5ogFRaQwqHrtCe2MLqx1KzA5cjW5Q4hYeX7AphDQo4gbax7GKXr/57kic6pIPVcjrswYYzHSFQOwBygJ7NhxYXfxA2ETEFlnNVusAtt8RpSEpjd3KQCvrAkezaRJcCex8o1QYETGaVvVPdPO0nMPLdjY1wX29aIakofe09e4w/4w9OMyt5zCJiaMc9vvxjNUPzaKjOqzMu6T99N5Oh0l7KtZH9WMC83Dj@@vAt6ajDKSISUj6sP8Q9@//0/fAvz3dhTeLxa952Aa6HH1b7Ep9ce1g8jkenJajqWsHCstxGQh@unbV8d9mXz2WV3YZyq9P/wE)

Unfortunately, *krrp* only has one rather slow implementation, making the long test cases difficult to verify.
[*krrp* String conversion](https://tio.run/##TVJBTsMwELznFSurB1CVvmDZC3DrjSNiJSsgJaJtosSYC38PM2sORJVrj2dnZycZ8/b5cbns@3Rd5rXIUy759DjmtfsPnKetdN2SyygPkqpVddeq6uqmau5mpoCrYwEEEJAm6XtRrcQrbgw/nFCr5Dq4aqiGGlaImjcyZKDNDkZ9FEKUHJwhUsHjPcWqoqGFfLjg0fFEDe2wobKA/kDwMM32uAKbNtTZVRtMW0ayBlFphjzaB0Ep4Q3mnBQPWbfohMdpjt5RoNElJKLaowPVOZaGX15XbfMyKaQAdW85xHzWvFokGB0sOkSqGos3xfDN0TkVU@RotBcvjSnxHzvSGS/fA7dU879TBGbccNdaMgkaZ7paU9dd83TD57B8lZeyykGG@TbkIq/pfEhyPMrdNs7fwOf1XYZ7IumU5EcG0V74Lb0F9pz2/Rc).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

Inspired by orlp's C solution. Assembles a list of all visited positions, and then for each unique one (using setwise intersection `(d&d)` since it saves a byte over `d.uniq`), count the ones with an odd number of occurrences (technically, map it to the occurances%2, and sum them together, since that does the same thing)

```ruby
->s,q=0{d=s.bytes.map{|c|q+=1i**(c%11)}
(d&d).sum{|c|d.count(c)%2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVHRToNAEHz3K3ypgapEfB72R5puYqFVH7BU4JKm5dtxZk9Cjru92ZnZ4Xc@XNdTs77a@HJp3m5dM1aH63Qcq/5juN3b@@W5qb@326Ld1HW5PBTdU1dW49zrrqva8/wzFW25eV@WdXg87T6P01i1X@d@2K/JEtyRAIcbYO5mBpaTc2GJRZYAJJUSi8aXJ7ZBMCcMxkYScSWfeQaTgbQiF4EayScMzyRJxOleZAnUsqAPAzo6n@iREwlCDbJGgIdfyfOKaNmASxW5LFsmMAIImRFO9gmAKDyXNaLIg9YtlPi4zMk7GxAqQRHdHgpi11gIv7pOyPMqKaZAds85xHyWvVokGAoWCpEqYvHMGL41uqZSihpN9uJ/KSV9uRNc8eo/aCs2/z9FYKaNdllSSci40kX6Aw)